# What Does Adding One to a Character Array in C Do?

Tags: c, char, memcpy, arrays, operands

I'm looking through some code for learning purposes. I'm working through this portion of code.

```
// e.g. const unsigned char data={0x1,0x7C ... }
unsigned char buf[40];
memset(buf,0,40);
buf[0] = 0x52;
memcpy(buf+1, data, length); // What does buf+1 do in this situation?
```

On the last line where memcpy is called what does buf+1 do? buf is a character array, so what does +1 do to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, every array name is a pointer, so buf here also means the pointer which point to buf[0].Then "buf+1" means "buf[1]"'s address.

Comment: Ah cool. I had a hunch that was what it was doing, but the syntax did make sense to me. Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Comment: More correctly, if an array is used in an expression where it isn't the subject of the `sizeof` or `&` operator, it evaluates to a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 5):

`buf+1` is equivalent to `&(buf[1])`

Answer (score 3):

`buf+1` is the same as `&(buf[1])`. In other words, it returns a pointer to the 2nd (index 1) character of buf.

Answer (score 0):

[Pointer Arithmetic (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)