# GDB arithmetics

Tags: gdb

When i use the commands:

print/x &_start -> i get: 0x08049054
print/x &_key   -> i get: 0x0804916d

It is quite easy to figure out that the difference is: 119h

But if i use the command:

print/x &_key-&_start  -> i get: 0x46 (!!)

Why? Does anyone confirm this if debug a program of his own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is pointer arithmetic.

See also: [SO:Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use pointers to an `unsigned int` or some other type (for `_start` and `_key`) that is four bytes wide. You will notice that even with pointer arithmetics in C/C++ you get the same results.

Write this into `foo.cpp`:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  unsigned int* _start = (unsigned int*)0x08049054, * _key = (unsigned int*)0x0804916d;
  printf("start(%p), key(%p) -> [key - start](%li)\n", _start, _key, _key - _start);
}
```

Now the make file (`GNUmakefile`):

```
CXXFLAGS=-ggdb -g3 -O0

foo: foo.cpp
```

Build it by invoking `make` (GNU make, to be precise).

The output will be:

```
start(0x8049054), key(0x804916d) -> [key - start](70)
```

... and `70 == 0x46`.