# Difference of two addresses in C

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

The given code

```
int arr[12];
int * cur = arr;
cur++;
cout<<"cur-arr = "<<cur-arr<<endl;
```

Outputs `1`, but I expected `sizeof(int)`. Can someone please explain the nature of this behavior?

Comment: What don't you understand about that? What were you expecting?

Comment: This is [pointer arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic).

Comment: What do you think `cur++` does?

Comment: i think he expects `sizeof (int)` in output

Comment: C? Then why is the question tagged C++?

Comment: Please explain the nature of the confusion emergency.

Comment: All your questions that I've seen so far seem to be of the "confused, please explain" variety, but this is a Q&A site not a forum. So, ask questions. "I expected X because of Z, but I got Y. Why did I not get X instead?"

Comment: @phonix: Almost certainly, but we want _him_ to tell us that.

Comment: ya ... i had expected the sizeof (int) to be the output..anyways its clear now !!!!

Comment: @Kunal: So please take better care over your questions in the future.

Comment: The better question is what made you think it returns `sizeof(int)`, since the book you learned from that you can subtract pointers pointing into the same array will surely have told you about basic pointer arithmetic...

Answer (score 4):

It's a defined behavior of C pointer arithmetic. It uses the size of pointed type as a unit. If you change subtraction in the last line to

```
(char *)cur - (char *)arr
```

you get 4 in the output.

Comment: That would be `char *`. You can't do arithmetic on `void *`.

Comment: Some compilers do allow `void *` arithmetic. `char *` is surely nicer.

Answer (score 3):

This is the number of elements (`int`s here) between `arr` and `cur` (which is `arr+1` at the time of subtraction). Compiler takes note that `cur` is a pointer to an integer and `arr` is an integer array. To get total number of bytes, try this:

```
(cur - arr) * sizeof(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`cur` is a pointer to `int`, initialized to some value (`arr` - the semantics of array-to-pointer conversion are irrelevant here), incremented (`cur++`) and compared to its old value. Unsurprisingly, it grew by one through the increment operation.

Pointer arithmetic with a given type works just like regular arithmetic. While the pointer is advanced by `sizeof(int)` bytes in this example, the difference between pointers is also calculated in units of `sizeof(int)`, so you see plain simple arithmetics.

Comment: That's not quite *incrementing*, the pointer itself grew not by one. It grew by `sizeof(int)`, but the pointer substraction operator returns difference in **elements**, not in bytes.

Comment: @ulidtko: It doesn't really matter. When you take the abstraction into account, it's certainly an increment, even though the underlying value increases by more than `(int)1`.

Answer (score 1):

Addition and substraction for pointers works in accordance to the pointer type.