# Pointer data types in C

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

If I have a pointer like:

```
int* ptr;
```

and I do:

```
printf("%#x\n%#x\n%#x\n", ptr, ptr+1, ptr+2);
```

I get the output as:

```
some address
some address + 4bytes
some address + 8bytes
```

Now if I make the pointer `short int* ptr`

I print in the same way as above and get the output as:

```
some address
some address + 2bytes
some address + 4bytes
```

Why is that? Aren't addresses unsigned integers? If so, then the datatype to which a pointer is pointing to should not matter. The pointer will always store an address which is an unsigned int hence it would occupy 4 bytes. Why is a short int pointer occupying 2bytes whereas an int pointer is occupying 4bytes? In the end, both pointers store addresses only, isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer Arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Comment: I get how pointer arithmetic works. I just don't understand why it works the way it works.

Comment: This is a feature of compiler. It counts at compilation time the number of bytes to add it to the pointer value.

Comment: It's UB to print addresses with `"%x"`. To be portable and Standard compliant you need `"%p"` and cast the address to `void*`.

Comment: all of the values above are unsigned integers. Can you point out any float here?. BTW you should accept the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Pointer arithemtic (i.e. `ptr+n`) is performed in units of the the thing being pointed to.

Remember than `ptr+n` is equivalent to `&ptr[n]`, so it's also equivalent to:

```
(T *)((char *)ptr + n*sizeof(T))
```

where `T` is whatever type you're pointing to.

---

<sub>By the way, you should be using `%p` to display pointers, not `%#x`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
int* ptr;
printf("%#x\n%#x\n%#x\n", ptr, ptr+1, ptr+2);
```

The compiler says "Hey, `ptr` is pointing to some `int`, and the programmer wants the `int`s at offsets of 1 resp. 2 ints. So, I get `sizeof(int)` (which is on many architectures, including yours, 4 bytes) and add it to the value of `ptr`". So the output will be offsets by 4 bytes.

Layout in memory:

```
ptr --+
      |
      v
      +---------+---------+---------+
      |   int   |   int   |    int  |
      +---------+---------+---------+
        4 bytes   4 bytes   4 bytes
```

When doing

```
unsigned int* ptr;
printf("%#x\n%#x\n%#x\n", ptr, ptr+1, ptr+2);
```

The compiler says "Hey, `ptr` is pointing to some `unsigned int`, and the programmer wants the `unsigned int`s at offsets of 1 resp. 2 ints. So, I get `sizeof(unsigned int)` (which is on many architectures, including yours, 2 bytes) and add it to the value of `ptr`". So the output will be offsets by 2 bytes.

Layout in memory:

```
ptr --+
      |
      v
      +---------+---------+---------+
      |unsigned | unsigned|unsigned |
      +---------+---------+---------+
        2 bytes   2 bytes   2 bytes
```

Comment: Okay I think I get it now. Size of 'ptr' is always 4bytes. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, `sizeof(ptr)` is -- on many architectures including yours -- 4, but the elements pointed to by `ptr` may just have any size.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetics differs from usual integer arithmetics. Compiler has in mind length of a variable type this pointer points to and adds to the address this length, not just a number 1, 2 and so on

Comment: If a pointer pointing to a short int is advanced by 2bytes everytime then doesn't that mean that the pointer length is 2bytes? If it is indeed 2bytes then how will it store an address that is greater than 2^16?

Comment: No, certainly  length of a pointer is not equal to the length of  data it points to. Werther I said not clear or you didn't understand me. )))

Comment: I get it now. I kept confusing the pointer size with the size of the datatype it is pointing to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, pointers store addresses. However when you say `int* ptr`, it **allocates 4 bytes in the memory**, so that any new allocation will not touch this area. Similarly short occupies 2 bytes hence it allocates 2 bytes in memory.

Bottom line: Pointers store address value which is common to all datatypes, but the capacity varies

You may read this: http://www.taranets.net/cgi/ts/1.37/ts.ws.pl?w=329;b=279

Answer (score 0):

yes pointers are unsigned integers ,Now Considering definition `int *ptr`

`ptr` dont represent the address of pointer , it represent the address of the variable that pointer is pointing and size will be dependent on the type of the variable it is pointing towards.
thou if you did something like this for pointer pointing towards any type , `printf("%x %x %x",&ptr,&ptr+1,&ptr+2)` , then the difference between addrresses  would be same