# Ambiguity in address difference in an Array

Tags: c, memory-address

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a[] ={ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    char c[] = {' a','x','h','o','k'};
    printf("%d ", (&a[3]-&a[0]));
}
```

The output of the program is 3. However , the difference in the outputs of values obtained below is 12.Can someone please explain the ambiguity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a[] ={ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    char c[] = {' a','x','h','o','k'};
    printf("%d     %d ", &a[3],&a[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called pointer arithmetics. The result is the values divided by `sizeof(int)`

If the difference in bytes is 12, and the size of `int` is 4, than the result is `12/4=3`

BTW, when printing addresses use the format specifier `%p`:

```
printf("%p     %p ", &a[3],&a[0]);
```

Comment: how `printf("%d     %d ", &a[3],&a[0]);` is printing the difference? I think, it should print the a[3] and a[0].

Comment: Read OP question. the difference between the printed addresses is 12.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the operator `'-'` is applied to a pointer and the result is measured in number of elements rather than in absolute addresses.
Check out this: [Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic) .

Answer (score 0):

you are printing the address

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 int a[] ={ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
char c[] = {' a','x','h','o','k'};
printf("%d     %d ", &a[3],&a[0]);

}
```

result

```
-1085768040     -1085768052
```

[codepad](http://codepad.org/G4SckZtX)

and for first one   Binyamin Sharet answer is perfect

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `a[i]` is automatically translated to `*(a+i)` by the compiler (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995156/226621 for an interesting consequence of this).  So, `&a[i]` is the same as `&*(a+i)`, or `a+i`.  This means that:

```
&a[3]-&a[0]
```

is the same as

```
(a+3) - (a+0)
```

which is `3`.  This also means that for `p` and `q`, both of which are pointers to some type `T` (i.e., `*p` and `*q` are of type `T`), and when `p-q` is valid, it gives you the number of elements of type `T` between `p` and `q`.  The compiler will automatically convert the difference in values of `p` and `q` and divide that difference by `sizeof(T)` to give you the correct number.

Therefore, when you print the individual pointer values, and then subtract those values yourself (in your head for example), you will get a number that is `sizeof(T)` times "too big".

On your machine, `12 / sizeof(int) == 3`, which means that `sizeof(int)` is 4.

Incidentally, to print pointer values, you should use `%p` specifier:

```
printf("%p %p\n", (void *)&a[3], (void *)&a[0]);
```