# C code iterators incrementing by sizeof(int) instead of by bytes

Tags: c, strong-typing, type-safety

Could somebody explain exactly what the following C code does please? Specially the first line and the iterated line?

```
int * p = &my_numbers[0];

int i;
int j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  j += *(p + (i));
}
```

Does the compiler (GCC) know that when I increment the iterator, that I mean by sizeof(int) / 4 bytes instead of one byte? Is this the same for every compiler? Originally I was using:

```
  j += *(p + (i * sizeof(int)));
```

but that gave the wrong answer, however:

```
  j += *(p + (i));
```

did give the correct answer.

What would I have to write if I wanted to increment by only a single byte? (not sure why I would want to do this, I guess maybe the strongly typed nature of the language would allow me to use char to tell the compiler maybe?).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic for a great explanation of this.

Comment: In addition to what @MichaelDorgan said, generally speaking, for a pointer `p` to some type `T` the operation: `p + i` is equivalent to: `p[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In pointer arithmetic, the pointer will be adjusted by the size of the type pointed to.

If you wanted single-byte pointer arithmetic, you'd have to use `char*` and casts. But you'd likely run into alignment problems if you're really dealing with `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

Since you used

```
int * p
```

The compiler knows it needs to find the next address that is 4 bytes away. If

```
char * p
```

was used instead, only a distance of 1 byte will be added each time.

The initial code

```
j += *(p + (i * sizeof(int)));
```

moves the pointer way past the address you would like it to be pointing at.

Comment: what would happen if I incremented `void *`, is that defined behaviour?

Comment: `void *` is a generic pointer. You must cast it if you want to do anything usable with it

Comment: @dje1990 C doesn't support + or - on a void*. However some compilers , such as gcc, provides it as an extension, in which case void* is incremented/decremented by 1 byte.

Comment: read the 'void pointers' section in http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ . Although it is a tutorial for C++, it shares a common explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Because p is an pointer to an `int` type, it's arithmetics are best suited for `int` type. If the pointer pointed to `char` then it would have incremented by `1 byte` .

Answer (score 0):

> Because p is an pointer to an int type, it's arithmetics are best suited for int type. If the >pointer pointed to char or void then it would have incremented by 1 byte .

Void pointer can't be incremented directly. You have to cast it to char, byte etc to increment it.

Comment: This should be a comment on the quoted answer. It is not an answer itself.

Comment: @CasperGhost : I edited that already . Anyways, `void` would literally mean nothing, so there would be no point on using it without casting

Comment: gcc supports arithmetic on `void` pointers as an extension (not that one should use it).

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic takes the size of the pointed-to type into account; given a pointer `T *p`, the expression `*(p + i)` computes the address of the `i`'th *element* of type `T` following `p` and dereferences it.