# What is wrong with this code, Can't I add pointer and a unsigned value together?

Tags: c, pointer-arithmetic

Test platform is Linux 32 bit.

I found a bug in my code, and I don't know why....

I simplified this code and put it here:

```
unsigned int aa  = 0;
unsigned int array[10000];
unsigned int* ptr = array + 2000;

printf("aa: %d ", aa);   // value 1
printf("ptr: %d \n", ptr);  //value 2
printf("aa+ptr: %d \n", aa + ptr);  // value 3
```

compiler is  gcc version 4.6.3

It seems silly but 
I don't understand why **value3 != value1 + value2**

Could anyone give me some help?

Thank you!

Comment: In cygwin (32-bit), with `gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)`
, I get the expected output: `aa: 0   ptr: 2633512   aa+ptr: 2633512`.  Are you posting your actual code?

Comment: Also, while you're playing with pointers, it may help to make sure you understand how [pointer arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic) works. Basically, adding one to a pointer advances it to the next "element", increasing the value of the pointer by `sizeof(*p)` bytes.

Comment: What values are you expecting, and what values are you actually seeing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second and third cases, you're passing a pointer to printf, but using %d as a formatter.  You need %p.

ints and pointers are not interchangeable.

Comment: But on Linux 32-bit, `sizeof(int)==sizeof(void*)`. Printing pointers with `%d` is largely useless, but this should still work just fine.