# Pointer arithmetic with NULLs

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone explain, why

```
int main(void)
{
    char *a = NULL;
    int *b = NULL;
    double *c = NULL;

    printf("\n%d %d %d\n%d %d %d\n\n",
    (int) (a+1), (int)(b+1), (int)(c+1),
    (int) (a+5), (int)(b+7), (int)(c+17));
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
1, 4, 8
5, 28, 136
```

I think it has something to do with the byte-sizes of those variables.
But I don't understand the second line of output.

Comment: Related: [Pointer Arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If `p` is a pointer to type `T`, and it holds memory address `X`, then `p + N` is the memory address `X + N * sizeof(T)`.

```
(int) (a +  1) == 0 +  1 * sizeof(char)   ==  1 * 1 ==   1
(int) (b +  1) == 0 +  1 * sizeof(int)    ==  1 * 4 ==   4
(int) (c +  1) == 0 +  1 * sizeof(double) ==  1 * 8 ==   8

(int) (a +  5) == 0 +  5 * sizeof(char)   ==  5 * 1 ==   5
(int) (b +  7) == 0 +  7 * sizeof(int)    ==  7 * 4 ==  28
(int) (c + 17) == 0 + 17 * sizeof(double) == 17 * 8 == 136
```

Minor note: As Barmar points out in his answer, arithmetic on NULL pointers is technically undefined behavior. So a standard-compliant compiler *could* have done something different with that arithmetic; the code might have printed 1, 3.1415, or a picture of dogs playing poker. But the behavior you observed is the same as the *defined* behavior you would've observed if you'd started with valid pointers, so you probably don't need to worry about this.

Answer (score 4):

In C, pointer arithmetic depends on the size of the underlying type.

When you do `p + n` on some pointer `p` you don't really add `n` to it. Instead you add `n * (sizeof(*p))`. That, is you advance the pointer by `n` items.

Answer (score 3):

```
a+5 = 0 + sizeof(char)*5 = 5
b+7 = 0 + sizeof(int)*7 = 28
c+7 = 0 + sizeof(double)*17 = 136
```

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic on null pointers results in undefined behavior, so any result is possible.

Comment: Should I start worrying that using offsetof macro starts to format my hard drive? (Well, you didn't say anything is possible under UB... but still...)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: No, as this macro is evaluated a compile-time. The question isn't about using `NULL`, but about reading pointers carring `NULL`.

Comment: Technically true, but the OP would've observed the same effect even if he started with valid non-NULL pointers. So this answer doesn't really answer the spirit of the question, which is the fact that pointer arithmetic is based on the size of the pointed-to type.

Comment: Under UB, I'd be still expecting that (int)a == (int)b == (int)c, and (c+5)-c == 5 * sizeof(double), regardless of encoding of NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic operations on `NULL`-pointers are undefined behaviour.

From the C-standard:

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> [...]
>   3
>   If a null pointer constant is converted to a
>   pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal
>   to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> [...]
>
> **6.5.6 Additive operators**
>
> [...]
>   2
>   For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
>   pointer to an object type and the other shall have integer type.
>
> [...]
>
> **Apx J.2 Undefined behavior**
>
> [...]
>
> Addition or subtraction of a pointer into, or just beyond, an array object and an
>   integer type produces a result that does not point into, or just beyond, the same array
>   object (6.5.6).