# Objective C Integer Math error (2200 - 100 = 1800) - Not sure why

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an IOS project that uses NSInteger to count opening and closing. The times are read at 2200 is equivalent to 10pm. I would like to see if something is within an hour of closing, so I compare the real world time in integer (works) to the closing time - 100 but the math isn't working as expected.

Custom class:

```
@property (assign) NSInteger *sus;
@property (assign) NSInteger *sue;
```

In Controller:

```
custom_class *location = object
resultINT = real world time in Integer with 24 hr

NSLog(@"Result INT:   %i", resultInt);
NSLog(@"location.sue:    %i", location.sue);
NSLog(@"Location - 1hr      %i", location.sue -100);
NSInteger *yellowEnd = location.sue - 100;
NSLog(@"Yellow      %i", yellowEnd);
```

result:

```
2014-07-13 18:23:51.269 Time-Genesis-Marcus[7591:416078] Result INT:   1823
2014-07-13 18:23:51.269 Time-Genesis-Marcus[7591:416078] location.sue:    2200
2014-07-13 18:23:51.269 Time-Genesis-Marcus[7591:416078] Location - 1hr      1800
2014-07-13 18:23:51.270 Time-Genesis-Marcus[7591:416078] Yellow      1800
```

Why isn't the third and forth lines returned 2100? thanks

Answer (score 5):

You are doing pointer arithmetic instead of integer arithmetic.

Change your code to this to fix the problem

```
@property (assign) NSInteger sus;
@property (assign) NSInteger sue;
```

---

For explanation of the result you got, read [Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Basically `(int *)2200 - 100` results `2200 - 100 * sizeof(int)` where `sizeof(int)` is 4

Comment: Thanks. Never considered Pointer vs. Variables in IOS dev