# What does "char *t = s + len" mean?

Tags: c, string

I'm going through a programming book and I'm wondering what a line of code does.  There are no comments in the book or explanations about what it's supposed to do.

Below is a function that takes a character array and prints it backwards.

```
void print_reverse (char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *t = s + len -1;  // I don't understand what this line is doing
    while (t >= s) {
        printf("%c", *t);
        t = t - 1;
    }
    puts("");
}
```

Comment: It's pointer arithmetic.

Comment: takes the pointer `s`, increments it by `len-1` objects, and assigns that pointer to `t`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic

Comment: take the code, and make a program using it. Then step through it in a debugger. A must have skill and habit

Comment: I don't think anyone understands that line so far because actually it produces undefined behaviour. Consider what happens when s is an empty string

Comment: @Brandin, it actually works exactly the same with an empty string as it does with a non-empty one. UB when you compare `t` and `s` when `t < s`. That situation arises _quicker_ with an empty string but it arises _always,_ regardless of the string.

Comment: @paxdiablo So what we've learned is that the book this came from belongs next to a fireplace

Comment: To simply prevent UB as pointed out by @Brandin, `char *t = s + len; while (t > s) { t--; printf("%c", *t); }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say `s` is the string `"PaxDiablo"`, stored in memory at location `1` thus:

```
         s
         |
         V
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
       | P | a | x | D | i | a | b | l | o | \0 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
Address: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

The expression `t = s + len - 1` (where `len` is 9 in this case) sets `t` to eight characters past `s`.

```
         s                               t
         |                               |
         V                               V
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
       | P | a | x | D | i | a | b | l | o | \0 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
Address: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

In other words, it gives you the address of the *last* character in the string.

The rest of the code then iterates over the string in a backwards direction, by decrementing `t` until it passes `s`.

---

Technically, this is undefined behaviour since you're only every supposed to compare pointers where they point to the same array on one character beyond (here we are comparing `t` where it's one character *before* the array), but you'd struggle to find a system on which this didn't work.

As Potatoswatter (I absolutely *love* some of the names people choose here on SO) points out in a comment, you can avoid that comparison by using the `do {} while` construct rather than `while {}`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printReverse (char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen (str);
    if (len != 0) {
        char *pStr = str + len;
        do {
            putchar (*(--pStr));
        } while (pStr > str);
    }
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

Comment: It would make more sense to me if the string was `"Fiddling Bits"`.

Comment: Awesome!! I understand now.  Thanks to all.  pm100, I've yet to use a debugger but your comment is noted.

Comment: … and, the way to avoid UB is with a `do … while` loop.

Comment: Your `do while` version dereferences `str-1` on empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `s` points to the string `"Hello"`. In memory, it looks like:

```
s --> [ H | e | l | l | o | \0 ]
```

Now, `char *t` declares a new pointer variable to a char value, that is initialized with `s + len - 1`, which is:

```
s ------                    ------- s + 5   // (len is 5 since strlen("Hello") is 5)
       |                    |
     [ H | e | l | l | o | \0 ]
                       |
                       ------------ finally, t = s + len - 1
```