# How does an uint32_t pointer work in this code?

Tags: c++, uint32-t

I'm really confused by how `uint32_t` pointers work in C++

I was just fiddling around trying to learn [TEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEA_(text_editor)), and I didn't understand when they passed a *uint32_t* parameter to the encrypt function, and then in the function declared a *uint32_t* variable and assigning the parameter to it as if the parameter is an array.

Like this:

```
void encrypt (uint32_t* v, uint32_t* k) {
    uint32_t v0=v[0], v1=v[1], sum=0, i;
```

So I decided to play around with uint32_t pointers, and wrote this short code:

```
int main ()
{
    uint32_t *plain_text;
    uint32_t key;
    unsigned int temp = 123232;
    plain_text = &temp;
    key = 7744;

    cout << plain_text[1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And it blew my mind when the output was the value of "key". I have no idea how it works... and then when I tried with plain_text[0], it came back with the value of "temp".

So I'm stuck as hell trying to understand what's happening.

Looking back at the TEA code, is the `uint32_t* v` pointing to an array rather than a single unsigned int? And was what I did just a fluke?

Comment: `I have no idea how it works` It works due to the magic of *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); it also applies to C.

Comment: Posted nearly 7 years after the launch of Stack Overflow, such a question is very likely a duplicate and ought to be closed. What are some candidates?

Answer (score 3):

`uint32_t` is a type. It means unsigned 32-bit integer. On your system it is probably a typedef name for `unsigned int`.

There's nothing special about a pointer to this particular type; you can have pointers to any type.

The `[]` in C and C++ are actually *pointer indexing notation*.  `p[0]` means to retrieve the value at the location the pointer points to. `p[1]` gets the value at the next memory location after that. Then `p[2]` is the next location after that, and so on.

You can use this notation with arrays too because the name of an array is converted to a pointer to its first element when used like this.

So, your code `plain_text[1]` tries to read the next element after `temp`.  Since `temp` is not actually an array, this causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939).   In your particular case, the manifestation of this undefined behaviour is that it  managed to read the memory address after `temp` without crashing, and that address was the same address where `key` is stored.

Comment: Ohh thanks for the explanation. I took the TEA code off wiki, which was written for C, so I guess I needed to rewrite it a bit for it to work properly in C++.

Comment: Why is reading from `plain_text[1]` is undefined behaviour? I understand that writing to it is.

Comment: @Andronius this part is the same in C as C++. You need to stop accessing out of bounds of variables!

Comment: @rozina because pointers may only be used to access the object they were assigned to point to

Comment: @rozina: Because the standard says so. And the standard says so because it would be ridiculous to require any particular behavior (even *implementation defined*) here. And even in practice you can get a variety of behaviors: e.g. segmentation fault.

Comment: @Hurkyl I would be very surprised that reading from memory would ever produce a segmentation fault. Writing to it is another matter. So the OP code is UB, how about the following code: `int buffer[10]; std::cout << buffer[1] << std::endl; ` To me this is equivalent code to OP's code. I doubt this is undefined. The value of `buffer[1]` is undefined, but the act of reading the memory location should not be.

Comment: @rozina: Why would reading be any different than writing in regard to segmentation faults? If you're not allowed to access a segment, you're not allowed to access it. Regarding `buffer[1]`, that's a perfectly valid (reference to an) object of type `int` whose only deficiency is being *uninitialized*.

Comment: ... also you should keep in mind that C describes a memory model where every object you ever create is completely isolated from every other object (caveat: an `int[10]`, of course, is composed of ten `int` objects that are 'consecutive' as far as pointer arithmetic is concerned, and other similar things). You're not even allowed to subtract pointers pointing into distinct objects; `int x, y; int *p=y-x;` is undefined behavior. An implementation can give it whatever meaning it wants, but the C standard itself offers no restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Formally your program has undefined behavior.

The expression `plain_text[1]` is equivalent to `*(plain_text + 1)` ([expr.sub] / 1). Although you can point to one past the end of an array (objects that aren't arrays are still considered single-element arrays for the purposes of pointer arithmetic ([expr.unary.op] / 3)), you cannot dereference this address ([expr.unary.op] / 1).

At this point the compiler can do whatever it wants to, in this case it has simply decided to treat the expression as if it *were* pointing to an array and that `plain_text + 1`, i.e. `&temp + 1` points to the next `uint32_t` object in the stack, which in this case by coincidence is `key`.

You can see what's going on if you look at the assembly

```
mov DWORD PTR -16[rbp], 123232 ; unsigned int temp=123232;
lea rax, -16[rbp]
mov QWORD PTR -8[rbp], rax     ; plain_text=&temp;
mov DWORD PTR -12[rbp], 7744   ; key=7744;
mov rax, QWORD PTR -8[rbp]
add rax, 4                     ; plain_text[1], i.e. -16[rbp] + 4 == -12[rbp] == key
mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
mov edx, eax
mov rcx, QWORD PTR .refptr._ZSt4cout[rip]
call    _ZNSolsEj              ; std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned int)
mov rdx, QWORD PTR .refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_[rip]
mov rcx, rax
call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E       ; std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))
mov eax, 0
add rsp, 48
pop rbp
ret
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Assembly is well beyond me but the logic really cleared things up for this little accident

Comment: Are you sure it is UB? I would think that `pointer[n]` is always well defined. In OP's case there is just no guarantee what will be at the memory address of `plain_text[1]`. Where `plain_text[1]` point's too is very well defined - the next memory location after `plain_text[0]`.

Comment: If it's any help, plain_text[2] return an int value too, wasn't anything I've typed, but it came back with something

Comment: @rozina It is absolutely UB, the only time you can use pointer arithmetic is when pointing to arrays, and expressions can only result in a pointer to an element, or one past the end.

Comment: @Andronius It's just going to show you whatever garbage value is at that particular address, don't do this.

Comment: I would like to see some evidence that it is undefined behaviour, I can't take your word for it. Your last comment also proves it is not undefined, since you know what the result of will be - so it is well defined. What will be at the memory address is undefined in this case ofc. But reading from a specific memory address is not undefined.

Comment: @rozina [expr.add] / 4, the pointer used in the expression, and the result of the expression, must refer to the same **array** object, or one past the end. `temp` isn't an array.

Comment: @rozina There is a note that mentions that `An object that is not an array element is considered to belong to a single-element array for this purpose`, so in this particular case the arithmetic itself is not undefined, but the act of dereferencing it certainly is. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ arrays decay to pointers, resulting in [array/pointer equivalence](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10e.html).

```
a[1]
```

when `a` is a simple type is equivalent to

```
*(a + 1)
```

If `a` is an array of simple types, `a` will decay at the earliest opportunity to the address of element 0.

```
int arr[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int i = 10;

int* ptr;

ptr = arr;
std::cout << *ptr << "\n"; // outputs 0
ptr = &arr[0]; // same address
std::cout << *ptr << "\n"; // outputs 0
std::cout << ptr[4] << "\n"; // outputs 4
std::cout << *(ptr + 4) << "\n"; // outputs 4
ptr = &i;
std::cout << *ptr << "\n"; // outputs 10
std::cout << ptr[0] << "\n";
std::cout << ptr[1] << "\n"; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR.
std::cout << *(ptr + 1) << "\n"; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR.
```

To understand `ptr[0]` and `ptr[1]` you simply have to understand [pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic).

Answer (score -1):

```
uint32_t *plain_text; // In memory, four bytes are reserved for ***plain_text***

uint32_t key; // In memory, the next four bytes after ***plain_text*** are reserved for ***key***
```

Thus: `&plain_text[0]` is plain_text and `&plain_text[1]` refers to the the next four bytes which are at `&key`.

This scenario may explain that behaviour.

Comment: Not necessary next bytes. The compiler can put them in any order and anywhere, since its not told to do anything special. And what about 64bit environments?

Comment: so plain_text[1] is the same as plain_text + 1?

Comment: @Andronius `x[y]` means `*(x+y)`

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen, What I said explains what happened in that case !!

Comment: Please edit it to show that it is for this special case, not in general. (And not my downvote)