# Char pointer arithmetic C

Tags: c, char, pointer-arithmetic

I am learning pointer arithmetic, and I came across something like this:

```
char *str1, *str2;

/* stuff in between */

int f = str2 - str1;
```

What is `str2 - str1` returning? Let's say `str1 = "foo"` and `str2 = "foobar"`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result as you've presented the question isn't defined. For pointer differencing to work correctly they must be from the same array sequence (dynamic, automatic, and even automatic VLA makes no difference). or the one-past address past the last element:

> **§6.5.6 Additive Operators (p9)**
>
> **When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object**; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` header. If the result is not representable in an object of that type, the behavior is undefined. In other words, if the expressions `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, the `i-th` and `j-th` elements of an array object, the expression `(P)-(Q)` has the value i−j provided the value fits in an object of type `ptrdiff_t.` Moreover, if the expression `P` points either to an element of an array object or one past the last element of an array object, and the expression `Q` points to the last element of the same array object, the expression `((Q)+1)-(P)` has the same value as `((Q)-(P))+1` and as `-((P)-((Q)+1))`, and has the value zero if the expression `P` points one past the last element of the array object, even though the expression `(Q)+1` does not point to an element of the array object.<sub>106</sub>

That said, if you rephrased so as to be compliant with the rules above, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const char *p = "Hello World";
    const char *q = p+7;
    printf("%td\n", q-p);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
7
```

and the reason is explained from the cited portion of the standard.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited**

The answer to this question depends on the situation.

1) In your situation, since the pointers aren't pointing at anything, the result will be garbage

2) If the two pointers are pointing at two valid memory locations in the program space, then the result will be the number bytes of memory in between those 2 location. Although that doesn't make any sense, and it is UB according to the C Spec, if the two pointers are not pointing to the same array or string. If the two pointers point at the same array or string then the result would be the number of elements in between two elements in the same array (When the pointers are pointing at those two elements inside that array). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic) SO question for examples and more explanation.

Comment: I'd say 2) only stands if both pointers point to the very same "object".

Comment: "the result will be the number bytes of memory in between those 2 location" is a common result, but not defined by the C spec - it is UB.  Other results are possible including program fault or a meaningless value in `f`.

Answer (score 0):

`f` = memory address in `str2` - memory address in `str1`. 
`"foo"` and `"foobar"` are values to these memory location these pointers point to.

Example:

If `str2 = 0x8000000a`

and `str1 = 0x80000000`

```
str2 - str1 = 0x8000000a - 0x80000000 
str2 - str1 = 0x0a
```

Comment: I'd say this only stands if both pointer point to the very same "object".

Comment: not necessarily, for example: `char * str2 = &a`, `char * str1 = &b` then the address is on stack and my above answer will have different and non consecutive memory locations.

Comment: Please see *WhozCraig*'s answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31738328/694576 (What are `a` and `b`, btw?)

Comment: `a` and `b` are local variables.

Comment: Also your wording is inaccurate, as "*memory address of str2*" would be `&str2`, whereas `str2 - str1` is actually referring to the address stored **in** the pointer variable `str2`.

Comment: Yes, thank you @alk, I did meant address stored in the pointer variables `str2` and `str1`

Comment: "address is on stack and my above answer will have different and non consecutive memory locations." is not specified by C.  A "stack" is not even specified by C.  That result is depends on the platform/compiler as it is undefined behavior.

Comment: You are right it is dependent on platform/compiler. That is why I have given an example in my answer for the memory location. And, the actual location is undefined behaviour for C and is different from your machine to mine.