# List of operators on pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, operators, standards, pointer-arithmetic

For a given raw pointer type in C++, `T* ptr`, what is the list of all the [operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions#Operators) defined on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer Arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of operators that I can think of:

1. The assignment operator - `ptr = some other pointer`
2. The dereference operator - `*ptr`.
3. The array operator - `ptr[N]`.
4. The member access operator `ptr->` if `T` is a struct/class.
5. The pre and post increment operators - `++ptr` and `ptr++`.
6. The pre and post decrement operators - `--ptr` and `ptr--`.
7. The increment and assign operator - `ptr += N`.
8. The decrement and assign operator - `ptr -= N`.
9. The unary `+` operator: `+ptr`. Note that this is not valid in C99. It is valid only in C++.
10. The binary `+` operator - `ptr + N`.
11. The binary `-` operator - `ptr - N` and `ptr1 - ptr2`.
12. Is equal to: `ptr == some other pointer`.
13. Is not equal to: `ptr != some other pointer`.
14. The unary not operator: `!ptr`.
15. Less than operator : `ptr < some other pointer`.
16. Less than or equal to operator: `ptr <= some other pointer`.
17. Greater than operator : `ptr > some other pointer`.
18. Greater than or equal to operator: `ptr >= some other pointer`.
19. The address of operator: `&ptr`.

Comment: What about `+ptr` and  `ptr += N` and `ptr -= N` and `ptr1 - ptr2`?  Put in loads of *and*s to make it clearer.

Comment: @PaulEvans, the unary + operator is not valid for pointers but the others you suggested are. I added them to my answer.

Comment: +1 Interesting, obviously `+ptr` does nothing but I suppose it makes sense not to allow it since `-ptr` wouldn't make any sense at all.  Obviously most compilers ignore `+ptr` as a courtesy -- but is it?  What if you meant `N+ptr` but lost through an accident of editing the `N`!

Comment: My gcc 5.2.0 with `-Wall` doesn't on cygwin 2.2.1(0.289/5/3) for either `ptr2 = +ptr1;` or `*(+ptr)`.

Comment: @PaulEvans, interesting. I get an error using gcc 4.9.3 on cygwin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93207/discussion-between-paul-evans-and-r-sahu).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
T* t;
```

dereference

```
(*t).foo
```

or

```
t->foo
```

pointer arithmetic

```
t = t + 10; t += 10; // will add 10*sizeof(T)
t = t - 10; t -= 10; // will subtract 10*sizeof(T)

--t;
++t;
t--;
t++;
```

access like an array: (usually frowned upon)

```
t[10]
```

Comment: @Vincent, that's probably because it does nothing.