# How offset of structure is calculated? Explain printf statement here?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, printf, offset

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
        unsigned char c;
        typedef struct name {
                long  a;
                int b;
                long c;
        }r;
        r re = {3,4,5};
        r *na = &re;
        printf("%d", *(int*) ((char*)na + (unsigned int) & ( (struct name *)0 )->b));
}
```

OUTPUT :

4

I would be  thankful if somebody explain in detail what printf statement is doing in this c program ? According to me `int` is casted . then `char` pointer is casted to `na`.  But I cannot understand what whole statement overall doing ? What casting doing here ? `b` is not pointer but it seems it is used as pointer. I have found this problem one of the c programming book.It seems be it calculate structure offset but I still not able to know how. Please help me to understand program in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code `&((struct name *)0)->b` is indeed known as the "offsetof" operation and is in fact a [well-known C macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof).

The idea is that if `a` is a structure of type `A` then `&a.b` is equal to the address of `a` plus the offset of `b` in `a`. Since here NULL is used instead of the address of `a`, the result is just the offset of `b` in structures of type `A`.

According to Wikipedia,

> This works by casting a null pointer into a pointer to structure st,
>   and then obtaining the address of member m within said structure.
>   While this implementation works correctly in many compilers, it has
>   undefined behavior according to the C standard,[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic) since it involves a
>   dereference of a null pointer (although, one might argue that no
>   dereferencing takes place, because the whole expression is calculated
>   at compile time)

So let's look at the expression in `printf` step-by-step.

The expression `(unsigned int) & ( (struct name *)0 )->b))` calculates offset of `b` in `struct name` as described above and casts the result to an integer. The result should be equal to `sizeof(long)` on most platforms.

The `(char*)na` in the code casts `na`, which is a pointer to `struct name` to a char pointer. This is required because `sizeof(char)` can be assumed to be 1 while `sizeof(*na)` is larger than 1. What we want to do is to use the address of `*na` as a raw numerical address instead of doing [pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic), so that if for example `na==0x1234`, then the result of `((char*)na + 4)` is equal to  `0x1234 + 4 = 0x1238`.

The sum results in a memory address. That address is equal to the address of member variable `b` in the object `na`, and is of type `char *`. Knowing that, the last step is to cast the address back to `int *` (because the type of `b` is `int`) and then to dereference the result (once again, we know that it points to `b`). The final outcome is the value of `b`, which is then printed.

Comment: My actual question is to understand that printf statement dear. Still I am upvoting your answer as you tried

Comment: @PunitVara: which parts are you still missing? I can expand on the answer. Once you understand the offsetof stuff, the rest is plain pointer arithmetic.

Comment: I am really thankful to you if you expand step by step that statement.

Comment: Good breakdown of the pointer arithmetic.  Basically, it's a convoluted way of saying `printf("%d", na->b);`

Comment: Thanks @dbush Why ending with unsigned int what is purpose of that one?

Comment: The `unsigned int` cast treats the offset address as a number instead of a pointer.  The updated answer describes it pretty well.