# Understanding pointers in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I'm trying to understand how pointers work and I'm stuck at this line

```
for (p = s + strlen(s) - 1; s < p; s++, p--)
```

I don't understand p what it's equated to.
can anyone help me?

here's the full code.

```
void Reverse(char *s){
    char c, *p;

    for (p = s + strlen(s) - 1; s < p; s++, p--){
        c = *s;
        *s = *p;
        *p = c;
    }
}


int main(){
    char ch[] = "!dlroW olleH";
    Reverse(ch);
    printf("%s", ch);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and find out.

Comment: There is no language C/C++.

Comment: p is not equated, it is being assigned

Comment: Read up on "pointer arithmetic". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic) is a question on that topic. Once you understand that then you will see that `p = s + strlen(s) - 1` sets `p` to point to the last (non-NUL) character in the `s` string.

Comment: @kaylum, ok i'm going to read that.

Answer (score 0):

On the statement: `for (p = s + strlen(s) - 1; s < p; s++, p--)`

```
`p` contains the pointer to the end of the `s` string.
`s` contains the pointer to the beginning of the string.
`strlen()` calculates the length of the string
```

So in the beginning `p = s + strlen(s)` is assigned only once and translates to `p = <starting point of the pointer of the s string> + <length of s string>`

Then `s` increases his position and `p` decreases his own.

Inside the `for` loop position they just swapping characters using `c` like temporary variable.

Example for the word `hello`:

```
1) hello
2) oellh
3) olleh
```

Comment: I'm confused, with s + strlens(s). What is s ? an address? . and the function strlen(s) -1 is the number of char?

Comment: I Updated my answer. It's understandable?

Comment: yes! thank you very much!

Comment: Also can you not say "reference" when you mean "pointer", please. It's very confusing, and indeed wrong on a question tagged [tag:c++].

Comment: @PreferenceBean strictly talking you are right. I have a broader background i'm not using only `c` but either way i modified the answer to comply with the terminology.

Comment: @CodeArtist: Many of us have a broader background! I doubt anyone here knows _just_ C and C++, but the question is specifically about those languages. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

In this example the for loop is going backwards through s as the idea is to reverse the data held in s. P is being assigned the last memory location of s and though pointer arithmetic (p-- in the code) is going backwards through s. To access the data in each memory location the pointers s and p are dereferenced by putting * in front of each variable (*p).

Does this make it any clearer?