# Type of pointer arithmetic

Tags: c++

I am looking at some old code of mine that manipulates data buffers. I have many places that have:

```
char *ptr1 ;
char *ptr2 ;
```

And then I need to find the number of bytes between the two.

```
int distance = ptr2 - ptr1 ;
```

I am getting a lot of warnings about truncation. What is the type of

```
 ptr2 - ptr1
```

I have found a number of answers dealing with pointer arithmetic but, oddly not an answer to this particular question.

[Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Comment: It may be that you are on a 64-bit platform which would mean that your pointers are actually 64-bit addresses. If you change the LHS type to a 64-bit integer the warning will probably go away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result of subtracting two pointers† is a `std::ptrdiff_t`. It is an implementation-defined signed integer; it could be larger than what an `int` could store.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t for more information.

†You can only subtract pointers if they point to elements of the same array, otherwise it's UB.

Comment: They are circular buffers so it works. I am shocked at the number of warnings from integer conversions in this code that was clean. The C++ gods have taken a path that is not sustainable. Has C++ added an integer cast with range checking? Cast long to short and checks that the value is within the short range?

Comment: @user3344003: I haven't been keeping up with the latest C++ stuff, so C++14 or beyond might have a utility, but I don't think so. IIRC Boost has `numeric_cast` which will do actual checking before constraining the range into a smaller target type. In your case, this would be overhead because you presumably have guarantees in the implementation that your buffer size fits within an `int`. This is a good use for `static_cast`, then, telling the compiler "I know this is safe, please use `int`". You may want to `assert()` this prior, as a safety precaution for future developers.