# Why when i add number to string it shows random text in c++?

Tags: c++, string, int

When i try to add text to string i get random values.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "333" + 4;
}
```

I get some random text like:`↑←@`

Comment: I'm just curious: what exactly do you expect to get?

Comment: [pointer arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/394774/620908) - [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+pointer+arithmetic)

Answer (score 5):

`"333"` is a `const char [4]` not `std::string` as you might expect(which by the way still doesn't have `operator+` for `int`). Adding 4, you're [converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) it to `const char *` and then moving the pointer by `4 * sizeof(char)` bytes, making it point to memory with garbage in it.

Answer (score 1):

**It happens because those are two different types and the adding operator does not work as you may expect.**

If you intend to concatenate the string literals **"333"** with the int value of **4** than you should simply use count like:

```
cout << "333" << 4; // outputs: 3334
```

If you want to display the **sum**, than use string to int conversion with the `stoi()` function.

```
cout << stoi("333") + 4;  // outputs: 337
```

**Note:** When using stoi(): If the string also contains literals, than the conversion will take the integer value from the beginning of the string or will raise an error in case the string begins with literals:

```
cout << stoi("333ab3") + 4; // same as 333 + 4, ignoring the rest, starting a
cout << stoi("aa333aa3") + 4; // raise error as "aa" can't be casted to int
```

Comment: They're not incompatible, but the operation that is performed is pointer arithmetic, not addition or concatenation.

Comment: OP wants to add text to string, not number to number

Comment: @Quentin they are not incompatible, that's right, but even if this is a legit pointers arithmetic operation, you should see that is not the one the asker expects. So I was meaning they don't fit for getting the expected result. As long as the result is not the one it was expected you can be sure he doesn't wanted pointer arithmetics (even the asker haven't specified it). 
So, my point was that you can not combine dogs with birds to get planes...
Answer updated, thanks for pointing. It may have mislead others, maybe, as I wasn't so explicit.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to add text to text, solution would be to use proper types:

```
cout << std::string( "333" ) + "4";
```

or for c++14 or later:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
cout << "333"s + "4"s;
```

Answer (score -3):

I honestly do not know what you are trying to achieve by adding int to string. In case you want to add 333+4, you need to Parse string in to int like this :

edit:Typo
    #include

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << std::stoi("333") + 4;
}
```

Comment: Aside from the terrible `using namespace std;`, this does not compile.

Comment: My bad, had typo : std::stoi("333")+4;