# Adding a size_t variable to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, addition, size-t

I want to add a size_t type to a pointer. Some like this:

```
void function(size_t sizeA,size_t sizeB){
    void *pointer;
    pointer=malloc(sizeA);
    pointer=pointer+sizeB;
}
```

In the hipothetic case that this will not end in a segfault, the question is: Can I do this? Add a type size_t to a pointer? And the resulting address will be in the address 'size'?

Comment: Short answer is yes. For pointer arithmetic see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic

Comment: @sg7 It's trickier than that, because C does not allow pointer arithmetics on `void*`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are right about C. My C++14 compiler gives just a  warning: "pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I do this [add `size_t` to a pointer]?

Yes, you can, provided that you cast `void` pointer to some other type:

```
pointer = ((char*)pointer) + sizeB;
```

The type of the pointer determines by how much the pointer is to be advanced. If you cast to `char*`, each unit of `sizeB` corresponds to one byte; if you cast to `int*`, each unit of `sizeB` corresponds to as many bytes as it takes to store an `int` on your system, and so on.

However, you must ensure that `sizeB` scaled for size of pointer to which you cast is less than or equal to `sizeA`, otherwise the resultant pointer would be invalid. If you want to make a pointer that can be *dereferenced*, scaled `sizeB` must be strictly less than `sizeA`.

Comment: First paragraph is a nice description of what is frequently called the "stride" of pointer arithmetic. The OP would do well to commit it to memory.

Comment: what if we casted it to `void*` instead of `char*` ?

Comment: Late comment, but for those who come across this in the future -- first, the best practice is to cast to a `uintptr_t` for adding `size_t`'s. (see `<cstdint.h>`).   Next, if you add an integer to a `void` pointer, some compilers will add `sizeB` to pointer, as if pointer were a `uintptr_t` (i.e. add `sizeB * 1`).   Other compilers will generate an error.   In any case, it's not portable.

Comment: Late comment, but for those who come across this in the future: The `<cstdint.h>` above should be a `<cstdint>`.