# Adding a pointer to size_t in C89

Tags: c, c89, ansi-c

First, I know about this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444891/adding-a-size-t-variable-to-a-pointer):

Now Assume I have this array:

```
size_t    count = some_value();
struct info    *pinfos = malloc(count * sizeof(struct info));
```

and I wanted to "navigate" it using the variable

```
struct info     *p;
```

Can I use this code to check the limit?

```
p   <   (char*)pinfos  +  count*sizeof(struct info)  -  1
```

Is this legal in **C89**?

Is there a more "appropriate" way to do so?

Comment: Aside: `info` ==> `struct info`.

Comment: You do not need to fumble with a cast to `char*`. Pointer arithmetic works the same way as array indexing. The next element is `1` further along, regardless of the size of each element.

Comment: what does your first comment mean, please

Comment: `info` is not defined, as in `sizeof(info)`. You defined `struct info`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I corrected it, thank's

Comment: This is one reason why we like to see the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane It might be too long, and distract the reader.

Comment: Then it would not be "Minimal". Typos and "something like my code" are not good in questions. They make them hard to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that indeed but you are overcomplicating it, just do

```
p < pinfos + count - 1
```

and it will work because pointer arithmetic is performed in terms of the size of the pointer type.

Comment: Why the -1 ??  You're checking too short.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy because p will be incremented later on

Comment: Does this mean I can add (unsigned) integers (size_t in this case) to pointers freely?

Comment: @BiteBytes Indeed you can, but be careful with UB.