# Pointer to a member function

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue, pointer-to-member

having structure

```
struct Person{
    Person( int i , int g):id(i),age(g){};
    int id;
    int age;
};
```

i can dynamicly return member data by passing pointer to member data as argument to function. e.g

```
int extract( Person * p , int Person::* param)
{   
    return p ->*param;
}
```

and invoking using

```
Person *p = new Person (10 , 20 );
cout << extract(p , &Person::id )<< endl;
```

But my question is , why does this work? We are passing `&Person::id` basicly memory , but Person is an r-value which goes against definition.

I appreciate all explanation / clarification of my possible misunderstanding of topic.
Thanks.

Comment: `Person` is a type name, not an rvalue

Comment: `&Person::id` is internally represented as an offset into any `Person` object.

Comment: "We are passing `&Person::id` basicly memory" - what exactly do you mean by this? What is "basicly memory"?

Comment: There are no rvalues of type Person anywhere in your code. There are also no pointers to member functions so please change the misleading title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pointer to member in C++ can be understood as an "offset" definition. Although there are some complications when you have virtual functions etc, but in your case this is good enough.

So, basically your code is just like (if we turn data types to "raw" data)

```
int extract(void *p, int offset)
{
    return *((int*)(p+offset));
}
```

(technically speaking, the above code is not compile, because a `void *` pointer cannot be used in addition expression as the compiler don't know the size of the pointer, but let's ignore this for now.)

and when you call it, the code looks like

```
extract(p, __offsetof(Person, id));
```

where `__offsetof` is a pseudo operator that the compiler will calculate it at compile time.

You can see there is no magic here. What C++ helps you is that the offset is protected in a special data type, so you are not allowed to change its internal and so avoid breaking things apart.

**Additional information about C/C++ pointer casting and arithmetic**

The code above is quite basic to C/C++ users, although it is not the form a C++ professional would like to see (shall use `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` instead of C stype casting).

I see the question asker asks further explaining about C/C++ pointer arithmetic, and this is a bit off-topic as it have nothing to do with the question asking here, so instead I give some further reference about this topic.

[Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

http://www.technoplaza.net/programming/lesson9p2.php

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=686170&seqNum=8

Comment: thanks for answer, would you mind explaining return *((int*)(p+offset)); this is first time i have met with something like this. I assumed it was pointer to function but return type of function indicates it should be some derreference to function that returns poimter to int. Thanks!

Comment: @trolkura: It's shorthand for `*reinterpret_cast<int*>(p+offset)`. Also, it's used here to suggest a possible implementation. Actual compilers may work differently, especially after optimization.

Comment: @trolkura Also, you need to know that `int` is very different thant `int*`. The former is the type of integers like `123`, and the later is the type of a pointer pointing to an `int`.