# IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER's VirtualAddress and PointerToRawData difference

Tags: c++, windows, portable-executable

In [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) article, the definitions are

`DWORD VirtualAddress`

> In EXEs, this field holds the RVA to where the loader should map the section. To calculate the real starting address of a given section in memory, add the base address of the image to the section's  VirtualAddress stored in this field.

`DWORD PointerToRawData`

> This is the file-based offset of where the raw data emitted by the compiler or assembler can be found. If your program memory maps a PE or COFF file itself (rather than letting the operating system load it), this field is more important than the VirtualAddress field. You'll have a completely linear file mapping in this situation, so you'll find the data for the sections at this offset, rather than at the RVA specified in the VirtualAddress field

Also `RVA` is defined as

> Many fields in PE files are specified in terms of RVAs. An RVA is simply the offset of some item, relative to where the file is memory-mapped

and

> To convert an RVA into a usable pointer, simply add the RVA to the base address of the module. The base address is the starting address of a memory-mapped EXE or DLL

The problem in hand is to reach the `import section` of a PE file.

```
hFile = CreateFile(..);
hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(..);
lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(..);
ImageBase = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpFileBase;
PEHeader = (ImageBase + ImageBase->e_lfanew);
```

Now to get hold of `import table`

```
PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER PEImageOptionalHeader = &(PEHeader->OptionalHeader);
IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY importTable = PEImageOptionalHeader->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
```

Since `importTable.VirtualAddress` is an RVA, to get a usable pointer, i can add the base of the image file.

So `ImageBase + importTable.virtualAddress` should get me to import section.**But it does not.Why?**

Then, if i reach at the correct section header(generally `.idata`) and do this.

```
ImageBase + pointerToSection->PointerToRawData;
```

The above correctly takes me to array of `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORS`.I understand that using `pointerToSection->virtualAddress` instead of `PointerToRawData` above, would not work as i am mapping the PE file myself.

Now to get the `name` of the item, the loaded module is dependent on,I can use pointer to `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTORS` using the field `name` which is again an`RVA`.To convert an `RVA`, i just have to add the `ImageBase`..

```
 LPSTR libname = (PCHAR)((DWORD)ImageBase+ImageimportDescriptor->Name);
```

**But it does not work.Why**?To convert an `RVA`, we simply add base address of image.The below works

```
ImageBase+ImageimportDescriptor->Name + pointerToSection->PointerToRawData - pointerToSection->virtualAddress
```

And every time i need some info within a section, i need to make this adjustment

```
pointerToSection->PointerToRawData - pointerToSection->virtualAddress
```

**Why is this adjustment required?**

Comment: at first in `CreateFileMapping` are you use `SEC_IMAGE` flag ? section can be mapped as image and in plain mode. depend on this need use `VirtualAddress` or `PointerToRawData`. then `ImageBase + ImageBase->e_lfanew` really ? if `ImageBase` defined as `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER` this is of course error. `(DWORD)ImageBase` - again huge mistake. need `(DWORD_PTR)ImageBase` use

Comment: `But it does not work.Why ?` all is great worked when code is correct.

Comment: @RbMm I am not using the `SEC_IMAGE` flag.I'll read more about that.And why `ImageBase + ImageBase->e_lfanew` is an error.The exact code is `PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS PEHeader =(PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)ImageBase+ImageBase->e_lfanew);`What is wrong in this?

Comment: `(DWORD)ImageBase` - truncated pointer (which 8 byte on x64) to 4 bytes - error. and if `ImageBase` is defined as `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER` - simply pointer arithmetic. if you not use  `SEC_IMAGE` - section mapped in plain mode. you can not direct use RVA but first convert it to offset. and you want direct parse pe sections/data or use system api for this ?

Comment: Suppose i have `ImageBase` as `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER`.Then how can i get to the `PIMAGE_NT_Headers` ?I am directly parsing it.

Comment: `(PBYTE)ImageBase + ImageBase->e_lfanew` or `(DWORD_PTR)ImageBase + ImageBase->e_lfanew` or `RtlImageNtHeader(ImageBase)`. for convert RVA to offset you for example can use `RtlAddressInSectionTable`

Answer (score 7):

First, this line:

```
PEHeader = (ImageBase + ImageBase->e_lfanew);
```

Is incorrect. `ImageBase` is of type `PIMAGE_DOS_HEADERS` so when you add to it `ImageBase->e_lfanew`, which is a `DWORD` you are doing [pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic), that is, you are adding to `ImageBase` as many bytes as `(ImageBase->e_lfanew)*sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADERS)` which is not what you want. What you want is to advance `ImageBase->e_lfanew` bytes form the place `ImageBase` points to. You achieve this by doing the following:

`PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS PEheader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((PBYTE)(ImageBase) + dosHeader->e_lfanew);`

Notice the cast to `PBYTE`, this makes the operation advance byte by byte.

This is very common when dealing with PE file since many times you want to advance n bytes from a pointer and not n data structure the pointer points to.
In the [article you refered to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) it even says in a comment:

```
// Ignoring typecasts and pointer conversion issues for clarity...
pNTHeader = dosHeader + dosHeader->e_lfanew;
```

Now to **your question** about `VirtualAddress` and `PointerToRawData`:

The line `ImageBase + importTable.virtualAddress` is also incorrect for the following reason:

The PE Loader doesn't map all the executable file continuously in memory like you do in your file mapping, it maps each section at its corresponding `VirtualAddress`. In the latter situation, to get a VA from an RVA you just add the `ImageBase` to the `RVA` and it works, because the file on disk is meant to be a representation of what the PE loader maps in memory. However, since you are not mapping each sections where the PE loader would map them, adding the `ImageBase` to an `RVA` like you did doesn't work.

You need a function that given an RVA, gives you the file offset corresponding to that RVA in the file on disk. to get a VA you just need to add this file offset to the byte pointer that points to your mapped file.

Whenever you have an RVA (like the RVA to the import section, or to a name string or whatever), in order to access it you must do the following.

`PBYTE actualAddress = (PBYTE) (lpFileBase + RVAtoFileOffset(pNTHeader, RVA))`

Here is the function: I [posted it on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pttDSTRz) because I can't manage to format it correctly here.

Here is how it works: When you have an RVA, that RVA must lie within a section, so you traverse all section headers (which are right after the optional header) and whe you find the section where the RVA lies in, you calculate the offset of that RVA within that section `RVA - VirtualAddress` and add it to the `PointerToRawData` of that section, now you have the file offset of the RVA.
If the RVA is invalid (it doesn't lie within any section), the function returns 0.

You need to do this in order to access the import directory or the name of each import descriptor, since what you have are RVAs.

I hope I have helped.

Comment: if we add that value (rva - virtual address) to PointerToRawData, then PointerToRawData is basically the first byte of the section?

Comment: @Trey yes, PointerToRawData is the offset within the file of the first byte in a section. That first byte will end up being mapped at the VA (VA = RVA+ImageBase).

Answer (score 1):

Once we have valid PE/NT header address we can directly jump to first section:

```
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader;
sectionHeader = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(peHeader);
```

Also we can find name of section by masking

```
sectionHeader->Characteristics
```