# How to increment pointer value and pointer address in structure

Tags: c

[image]

How can I increment the address of the pointer which is defined in structure? I have defined a pointer in the main function that points to the structure. If I use `ptr->element`, where element is a pointer inside the structure, is it referring to the value pointed by the element? If yes, how can make the element point to the next location?

Comment: It would help if you added your code to the question. See [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: I am using ptr->element, but it seems it is accessing the value pointed by element. What I want is to increment the element so as to point to next location.

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: hey, I have added the code by editing my post. Just click on enter image description

Comment: @VikrantWaje, please don't post screenshots of code. It is very easy to post code itself, which makes it much easier for people to answer your question. see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: So what are you trying to increment? Are trying to increment the `char*` member, as in go character to character until you reach `'/0'`, are you trying to increment to the next struct member? What is your goal?

Comment: I am trying to increment the address of char *member ,not the value . I do not want to increment to next struct member. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's implementation-specific, but in practice the rule is:

Struct members are stored in the order they are declared.
 If necessary, `padding` is added before each struct member, to ensure correct *alignment*.

Each primitive type Ntype requires an alignment of `sizeof(Ntype)` bytes.

So, given the following struct:

```
struct Ntype
{
   char ch1;
   short sh;
   char ch2;
   int *a;
};
```

- ch1 is at offset 0
- a padding byte is inserted to align
- sh at offset 2
- ch2 is at offset 4, immediately after s
- 3 padding bytes are inserted to align...
- a at offset 8

So `sizeof(Ntype)` is 16.

Comment: in above program, how can i refer to address of pointer* a in struct Ntype (increment or decrement the address) using pointer from main function. I know we can access the value of a using following construct: mainptr->a. I am confused how can i increment the address of a

Answer (score 0):

To increment the address of the `char*` member, You would do the following:

```
//assuming that CB_t is already allocated.
char *temp = CB_t->buffptr;
//now you can increment temp as so
char myChar = *temp;
temp++;
char nextChar = *temp;
temp++;//and so on. You can also put it in a loop, where you end condition would be encountering a '\0' character.
```

Don't do this: `CB_t->buffptr++` as it will ruin your structure! If you do that, then `buffptr` will be trimming leading characters from member.

You can also do this:

```
char firstChar = *CB_t->buffptr;
char secondChar = *(CB_t->buffptr + 1);
char thirdChar = *(CB_t->buffptr + 2);//and so on
```

I would recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic) discussion about pointer arithmetic. It can be a tough concept to wrap your head around, but once you do you'll be armed with a very powerful weapon!