# Access UDP from ICMP message

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to catch all ICMP "destination unreachable - port unreachable" messages using RAW sockets in C++. And then process the underlying UDP protocol to find out for which port the destination was not reachable. So far I managed to receive the ICMP messages and filter them based on their type and code. However, I'm having hard time accessing the udp header. So far I tried these:

```
*(struct udphdr*)(icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr))
```

and

```
struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr*)ether_frame;
struct icmphdr *icmp = (struct icmphdr*)(ether_frame + ip->ihl*4);
struct iphdr *ip2 = (struct iphdr*)(icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr))
struct udphdr *udphdr = (struct udphdr*)(ip2 + ip2->ihl*4)
```

But neither one worked. I'm sure it's just some simple pointers arithmetic mistake, but I cannot figure it out. So my questions are: How exactly are the protocols organized in ICMP response? How can I access the port number which was unreachable from a raw icmp response?

EDIT: The socket used for receiving was created using `this->rcv_sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP` and the response is received using `recv(this->rcv_sd, ether_frame, IP_MAXPACKET, 0)`, where `ether_frame` is a `uint8_t` array of size `IP_MAXPACKET`.

Comment: "*How exactly are the protocols organized in ICMP response?*" - I suggest you use Wireshark or other similar packet sniffer+analyzer to see the actual packet structure for yourself.

Comment: Of course I did that, but it seemed to me, that my first try (`(struct udphdr*)(icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr))`) was the most relevant to what I saw in wireshark.

Comment: yes, otherwise i couldn't filter them based on the icmp's type and code. I also looked at them in gdb and their content was (as expected) identical to what I saw in wireshark.

Comment: just a typo in the question. should be fixed now.

Comment: ICMP and UDP are different things. You can't simply get one from the other.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: an ICMP "destination unreachable" or "port unreachable" packet contains a copy of the UDP/TCP packet that couldn't be delivered.  The OP is trying to extract that inner packet.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau ohh. I misunderstood then. I thought OP was trying to interpret the ICMP packet itself as a UDP packet. My bad.

Comment: @sveatlo, ICMP has a structure, it stores the original packet (well, not the whole packet, only the first xxx bytes) in a field, so I suggest you to point there, you'll find the IP header of the packet in trouble in the data section of the ICMP packet.  Also, the marked answer would be helpful:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [**pointer arithmetic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/), adding byte counts to struct pointers as-is, so statements like `(icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr))` and `(ip2 + ip2->ihl*4)` are not doing what you think they are doing, causing you to end up with wrong addresses.

When you add a number to a typed pointer, the pointer is adjusted by the number of bytes of the underlying type multiplied by the specified number.

So, this:

```
struct iphdr *ip2 = (struct iphdr*)(icmp + sizeof(struct icmphdr))
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
struct iphdr *ip2 = (struct iphdr*)(((uint8_t*)icmp) + (sizeof(*icmp) * sizeof(struct icmphdr)))
```

And this:

```
struct udphdr *udphdr = (struct udphdr*)(ip2 + ip2->ihl*4)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
struct udphdr *udphdr = (struct udphdr*)(((uint8_t*)ip2) + (sizeof(*ip2) * (ip2->ihl*4)))
```

Since you want to offset your struct pointers by bytes, not elements, you need to type-cast the struct pointers to byte pointers before adding the byte counts to them:

```
struct iphdr *ip2 = (struct iphdr*)(((uint8_t*)icmp) + sizeof(struct icmphdr))
// or simpler, using correct pointer arithmetic:
// struct iphdr *ip2 = (struct iphdr*)(icmp + 1)

struct udphdr *udphdr = (struct udphdr*)(((uint8_t*)ip2) + (ip2->ihl*4))
```

You don't have this issue when assigning your `ip` and `icmp` pointers from your `ether_frame` buffer because `ether_frame` is an array of `uint8_t`, which decays as-is to a `uint8_t*` pointer.