# How do I understand the "add" (+) operator when used in a C array expression?

Tags: c

I've been facing difficulties to understand the fourth line of code after the first curly brace,

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
     int arr[] = {10,20,36,72,45,36};
     int *j,*k;

     j = &arr[4];
     k = (arr+4);
     if(j==k)
        printf("The two pointers are pointing at the same location");
     else
        printf("The two pointers are not pointing at the same location");

  }
```

I just wanted to know what the fourth line of code after the first curly brace i.e. `k = (arr+4);` does?

Since `k` was a pointer it was supposed to point at something that had an "address of operator" ? I can still understand that if it doesn't have the "address of operator" then whatever does the part of the code `k = (arr+4)` do?

Comment: Ever heard of [pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic) ? Now you have. An array identifier, used in an expression as you've done here, converts to a pointer-to-type, pointing to the first element (slot 0) and then the arithmetic takes over.

Comment: The 'arr' array is treated as a pointer in most cases. The whole [] is just syntactic sugar. arr[4] is the same as *(arr + 4). Just to confuse you a bit, it's even possible, and legal, to write 4[arr]. The brackets just means p + offset, and the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah thats what the name of the topic that I'm reading is!

Comment: This is a valid question but I took the liberty to change the title to be more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks @CongMa I hope the downvotes don't kill my confidence to ask here !

Comment: @WhozCraig Could you please give me any link to any online data or tutorial that could teach me the same stuff with an even more descriptive manner?

Comment: The blue text in @WhozCraig's comment is a link to online data.

Comment: @usr2564301 okay thanks

Answer (score 2):

For any array or pointer `arr` and index `i`, the expression `arr[i]` is exactly equal to `*(arr + i)`.

Now considering that arrays naturally can decay to pointers to their first element, `arr + i` is a pointer to element `i`.

Comment: Could you please explain the origin of this expression since it is nowhere mentioned in the infamous textbook that I'm reading these days.

Comment: @kep This can be found for example in the [K & R book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language), 2nd ed, Chapter 5 Sections 5.3 and 5.4.  To quote: "The correspondence between indexing and pointer arithmetic is very close." :)

Comment: @kep It's part of the C specification. It's in ISO/IES 9899:2011 §6.5.2.1/2: "A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets **`[]`** is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator **`[]`** is that **`E1[E2]`** is identical to **`(*((E1)+(E2)))`**.

Answer (score 1):

Without `&` or the `sizeof` operator an array converts to a pointer to the first element of the array.In your case `array` will convert to a pointer to `int` and will point to the first element.`arr + 1` will point to the second element,`arr + 2` will point to the third element etc..`arr+1` means increment `arr` with `sizeof(int)`.

This is simplified diagram of the first 2 elements of the array.Let's assume `int` is 4 bytes long.

```
|       first element    |      second element   |
 -------------------------------------------------
|     |     |      |     |     |     |      |     |
|     |     |      |     |     |     |      |     |
 -------------------------------------------------
 0x00   0x01  0x02   0x03 0x04   0x05  0x06   0x07
```

`arr` will contain `0x00`

`arr + 1` will contain `0x04`

`*arr` will mean take the value from adress `0x00`.It's equivalent to `*(arr+0)`, `*(0+arr)`, `arr[0]` and `0[arr]`.Since `arr` is of type `int*` it will take a four bytes long value.

With `int* k = array` `k` will contain the same address with `array`.

`k = (arr + 4)` will contain the address of the 5th element.

`j = &arr[4];` will also store the address of the 5th element

Comment: Did you make the diagram directly on this comment? or you fetched it from somewhere else?

Comment: @kep  i did it myself

Comment: you must be a pro then martin

Answer (score 0):

As `k` is defined as pointer, it can be use to store address as value and can point to a location.
Here `(arr+4)` will return address of `arr` and plus `4`.
If `int` takes 4 bytes then it will point to 2nd element in `arr`, so it depends on system(32bit/64 bit), that how much it takes to store `int`.

Comment: Here, the array element that is `arr[4];` and `(arr+4);` have been shown to be the same, I hope you could run the program for yourself, it says they both point at the fifth element of the array thats `arr[4];`

Answer (score 0):

Something that you should aware of (C Standards#6.3.2.1p3):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

The statement:

```
int arr[] = {10,20,36,72,45,36};
```

`arr` is an array of `int`.

The expression `arr[i]`, can also be written as:

```
*(arr+i)
```

So, `&a[i]` can be written as:

```
&(*(arr+i))
```

The operator `&` is used to get the address and the operator `*` is used for dereferencing. These operators cancel the effect of each other when used one after another. Hence, `&(*(arr+i))` is equivalent to `arr+i`.

> `I just wanted to know what the fourth line of code after the first curly brace i.e. k = (arr+4); does?`

In the statement:

```
k = (arr+4);
```

none of the operators - `sizeof`, `_Alignof` and unary `&` is used. So, 
`arr` will convert to a pointer to type `int`. That means, `arr+4` will give the address of the four element past the object (i.e. `int`) pointed to by `arr`, which is nothing but `&a[4]`.

```
&arr[4] --> &(*(arr+4)) --> (arr+4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand *pointer arithmetic* here.

`arr[i]` is interpreted as `*(arr + i)`,

where `*` is 'dereferencing' or 'value at' operator and `arr` always represents the address of first element of the array i.e. the address of array itself, which literally means,

```
valueat(starting address of arr + i)
```

Now suppose address of `arr` is 100 and you are adding `i` elements of type arr in address of array and not the value of `i`, that is,

```
valueat(100 + i)
```

Now according to your code, here you are assigning address of 4th element to pointer `j` ,

`j = &arr[4];`
`j = &(valueat(100+ 4 elements of type int));`

`j = &(valueat(100+ 16));` ->
`j = &(valueat(116));` ->
`j = &(45)` that is `j = 116`

Now when you do

`k = (arr+4);`

`k = (starting address of arr + 4 elements of type int);`

`k = (100 + 16);` that is `k = 116`, and that is why the output,

`The two pointers are pointing at the same location`

Hope this helps.