# Allocate memory for different types in one block

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a question about dynamic memory allocation in C.
I am currently working on an artificial neural network implemantation in C.
I found and existing project called [genann](https://github.com/codeplea/genann) where I noticed a method of memery allocation I was no familar with.

Consider a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    int an, bn;
    double *a, *b
} foo;
```

And an init function:

```
foo *foo_init(int an, int bn)
{
    foo *f;

    f = malloc(sizeof(*f));
    f->an = an;
    f->bn = bn;

    f->a = malloc(an*sizeof(*f->a));
    f->b = malloc(bn*sizeof(*f->b));

    return f;
}
```

And here is a different init function like in the mentioned project:

```
foo *foo_init(int an, int bn)
{
    foo *f;

    f = malloc(sizeof(*f) + an*sizeof(*f->a) + bn*sizeof(*f->b));
    f->an = an;
    f->bn = bn;

    f->a = (double*)((char*)f + sizeof(*f)); // Could be f->a = (double*)(f + 1); ?
    f->b = f->a + an;

    return f;
}
```

So was thinking what are the differences between this two methods. The only advantage of the second method i could think of is that i only need to allocate and free one memory block, but since it is only an init function which is probably only called once, the performance difference should be insignificant. On the other side pointers of different types point to the same memeory chunk, but I think that doesn't violate the strict aliasing rule since they point to different memory within the chunk (?). Resizing could be difficult since it cant be done with a simple realloc like in the first init function. For example if i want to shrink a and b by one and I reallocate the whole memory block, the last two b values are lost (and not one a, one b).

My conclusion is that its better to allocate the memory in the first way, since the second has nearly only disadvantages. Is one of the init functions bad practice? Am I missing something, which would make the second function better? Maybe there is a particular reason why they used the second one in the project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @achal I don't believe so.

Comment: @achal: No it should be `*(f->a)` but since `->` binds stronger i need no brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allocate and free lots of these structures, the savings could add up to something that's significant.

It uses a little less space, since each allocated block has some bookkeeping that records its size. It also may reduce memory fragmentation.

Also, doing this ensures that the `a` and `b` arrays are close together in memory. If they're often used together, this can improve cache hits.

Library implementers often do these micro-optimizations because they can't predict how the library will be used, and they want to work as well as possible in all cases. When you're writing your own application, you have a better idea of which code will be in inner loops that are significant for performance tuning.

Comment: Yep. They are allocated all of the storage needed for a single `foo` struct in one memory allocation block (instead of as three separately allocated blocks), then setting the pointer members to point to parts of that block. This saves space and allocation time, and also makes deallocating the struct easier and faster.

Comment: @DavidRTribble: But how does it save space?

Comment: @Osiris It saves the bookkeeping space used by `malloc()` to record the size of each allocated block.

Comment: @Barmar: Ok i understand that i would save allocation and free commands. What you mean is that if I allocate everything in one block and often access elements of a and b combined the probability is high that this values are already in cache since the CPU usually loads the whole or part of the block in it, which would not happen if a and b are in completly different memory locations?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. This is called "locality".

Answer (score 1):

2nd approach problem.  The below can fail due to alignment.

```
f->a = (double*)((char*)f + sizeof(*f));
```

The pointer returned by `malloc()` is valid for all object pointers.  The computed `((char*)f + sizeof(*f))` may not meet the alignment requirement.  In *this* case, it is highly *likely* things will work, but not so for other `typedef`s.

Since C99, code could use a *flexible array member* to reap the [advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50514377/2410359) of a single allocation without risking UB.  Also simpler syntax.

```
typedef struct {
  int an, bn;
  double *a, *b;
  // Padding will be added here as needed to meet `data[]` alignment needs
  double data[];
} foo;

foo *foo_init(int an, int bn) {
  // `sizeof *f` includes space for `an,bn,a,b` 
  //  and optional alignment padding up to `data`, but not `data`.
  foo *f = malloc(sizeof *f + (an + bn) * sizeof *(f->data));
  if (f) {
    f->an = an;
    f->bn = bn;
    f->a = (double*) (f + 1);  // Guaranteed to align to f->data
    f->b = f->a + an;
  }
  return f;
}
```

---

Consider `size_t` rather than `int an, bn`.

---

There are ways using `union` to do this in pre-C99. Something like

```
typedef union {
  foo f;
  double data;
} both;

foo *foo_init(int an, int bn) {
  both *p = malloc(sizeof(both) + (an + bn) * sizeof *(f->data));
  foo *f = (foo *) p;
  if (f) {
    f->an = an;
    f->bn = bn;
    //                v--- Note p
    f->a = (double*) (p + 1);  // Guaranteed to align to p->data type
    f->b = f->a + an;
  }
  return f;
}
```

Comment: But is there actually a difference between `(double*)(p+1)` and `(double*)((char*)f + sizeof(*f))` since `sizeof` of a struct includes padding space? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394777/9017315) post it should have the same result. It looks cleaner to me, thats why I mentioned it in my question but i didnt know that it could make a difference.
EDIT: Oh you mean that the flexible array member adds additional padding which is required?

Comment: @Osiris Yes - I think you have it.  The FMA adds padding as needed.  In the 2nd case, padding is added too, if needed, to insure alignment should code have an array of `both`.