# Why this wrong syntax of printf is not producing error in c?

Tags: c

I have used this syntax for printing some variable n.
I know that the syntax is wrong but was not able to understand what is happening behind the scenes. It is not even creating an error.
Inside the main method:

```
int fac,p=1,n,i;
printf("Enter the value of n \n");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("The factorial is \n %d"+n);
```

I have used `+n`in last line and that is not the right syntax.
Input is 1 Output is:

```
he factorial is
1
```

Input is 5 Output is:

```
actorial is
1
```

Can someone help me to figure out what is happening behind the scenes? How is that the compiler understanding that `+n` in print function? From where the 1 is coming in the output?

Comment: And you entered 4? Do you get the same result with e.g. 1?

Comment: for every value of n it is giving 1 but if the value is large it is not generating any output. Even not the string.

Comment: There is more output than the "1", how about the text before. Does it change to "he factorial is " if you enter 1?

Comment: Yes in the output i can see changes in static as you can see in the output. The whole text is not printed.

Comment: Please show the exact output your get for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. I think you do not get the point of my comments. Keep in mind that **I** can **not** see the output **you** can see.

Comment: well the ans down is right :) just asking a bit of explanation

Comment: Input 1 | he factorial is 1 ,  Input 2 | e factorial is 1, Input 5 | actorial is 1 but from where the 1 is coming

Comment: Put those outputs into your question, on per line, aligned a little, to see what I mean and to improve your question.

Comment: Your change was incomplete, also it rendered existing comment/answer ununderstandable. I there rolled it back.

Comment: @Yunnosch added the output

Comment: As it stands the question does not makes sense, as the output shown does not match the code.

Comment: Read the comment by alk. Check the edits in the history. You are sabotaging your own question.

Comment: Oh God! That was my mistake...Just edited it.

Comment: @alk In case you are interested, the last edit seems to have fixed the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are just pointers to char arrays. When you add an `int` to a pointer, you perform pointer-arithmetic, and move the pointer. Here, your factorial was 4, so you moved the pointer up 4 characters, so you lose the `"The "`.

The `%d` will just take the following value off the stack and interpret it as an `int`. In your case, this just happens to be `1`.

Comment: Well expecting a bit elaborative explanation.

Comment: your ans seems to be correct can you please explain pointer-arithmetic in simple words ?

Comment: Ah. A challenge. Good luck @Mureinik , ;-)

Comment: @Ashishsah - probably a good idea to (re)read that chapter in a book.

Comment: @Ashishsah That means it increments the pointer by whatever you input, i.e It would more the starting point of your string forward, read more about it here  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm

Comment: and what about the 1 which is coming at the last of the output.

Comment: @Ashishsah If you have a pointer `p` pointing to an array element `a[i]` (as in `p == &a[i]`), then `p + n` is a pointer to `a[i + n]` (as in `p + n == &a[i + n]`). That's pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Did you read the answer after the last few edits? It answers the question where the "1" is coming from.

Comment: @Ashishsah in a nutshell, you move the pointer up and down the elements of the array according to the value of the int. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/394767/2422776 for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @Ashishsah  That is written in the answer.

Comment: Well sorry did not looked at your edit thanks for your help @Yunnosch