# Why printf("%s\n", "123456789" + 3); //output: "456789"

Tags: c

execution function:

```
printf("%s\n", "123456789" + 3); //output: "456789"
```

why output this result?
In the same way, what should I do if I want to output "123"?
Now I'm confused. Help me.

Comment: Try `printf("%d\n", 123456789 + 3);`

Comment: I want to use this feature to split strings.

Comment: You are getting bit by c's [pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic).

Comment: Splitting strings in C is not a trivial procedure like it is in many other languages. This is partly because C uses null-terminators as opposed to a length to determine how long a string is. To split a string, you need to allocate memory, copy part of the string to the new string, then truncate your original string.

Comment: "what should I do if I want to output "123"?" --> `printf("%.3s\n", "123456789");`

Comment: @user11376714 *I want to use this feature to split strings.* -- Choose a language, either C or C++.  This is becoming an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Your sample code does not split strings. It just ignores a few characters but they are still there in same place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**printf() is passed a pointer to a string constant incremented by 3**

```
printf("%s\n", "123456789" + 3);
```

printf() takes a format string argument followed by a variadic set of arguments.  In this case, the '%s' is the first (and only) variable in the format string.

There is only one argument in the variadic section after the format string:  a string constant:  "12345678" which resolves to a pointer to the '1' character; however, that pointer is incremented by 3 due to the "+ 3".  This moves the pointer 3 positions to the '4'.

Then, printf prints the string that starts at '4'.  As the string constant is terminated by a '\0' character right after the '9', printf prints "456789"

**Printing the first 3 chars of a string**
To print only the first 3 characters of a sting, use `%.3s` in the printf format string:

```
printf("%.3s\n", "123456789");
```

Comment: Thank you, @RingØ, once I read the first part of the question, I forgot to answer the second part.  I have edited the answer to provide the method to print 3 characters from a string without printing the entire string. `printf("%.3s\n", "123456789");`

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, strings are character arrays, meaning their name (variable name) points to the first element in the array.
For instance, in the array a[]={3, 4, 5}, a[0] is obviously 3.
However, the value of a itself is also 3 (like printf("%d", *a);)
If you increment a itself, you are incrementing the *address* of a, so the value of a + 1 would be 4.
Implicitly declaring a character array (what you did with the string) still requires the program to give it some form of address (That is, the location where the 1 in "123456789" is located)
That being said, incrementing the string itself basically acts the same as incrementing the array name, so "123456789" + 3 would give the address associated with "456789".
So what the printf basically sees is "print 456789".

I doubt I was able to explain this as simply as possible, or if you could even follow this, but I tried.

Best of luck!

Comment: Nope, the value of `a` itself is a pointer to the first element, not the value pointed to, so you have to dereference it (as you do with the `*` in front of `a`)  The value of `a` itself is not `3` as you post in your answer.  Please, edit your answer and add a comment mentioning me, and I'll take this comment off of the view.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One just can't add a string ("123456789") and a number (3).
What is it that you want? a) Integer addition or string concatenation?

```
a) 123456789 + 3
b) "123456789" + "3"
```

The compiler will not guess which option do you want!
So, one of the arguments needs to be converted to the type of the other, using some function such as (*unsafe*) `atoi()`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

`"123456789"` is a *string literal*. It is an object of type `char [10]` in C. It is an object of array type.

When an object of array type is used with binary `+` operator, it gets implicitly converted (decays) to pointer type. The resultant pointer value points to the beginning of the array. So, the original `char [10]` array decays to `char *` pointing to character `'1'` in `"123456789"`.

Binary operator `+`, when applied to a pointer, performs *pointer arithmetic*. Adding `3` to a `char *` pointer produces a pointer that points 3 bytes to the right of the original pointer. So, you get a pointer that points to character `'4'` in `"123456789"`.

After that you use format `%s` to ask ask `printf` to print a string that begins from that `'4'`. And that is the output you get.

---

The same thing happens in C++, except that in C++ this string literal has `const char [10]` type and decays to `const char *` pointer,