# Smashing the Stack - Trouble finding return address

Tags: c, exploit

I've been reading ["Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit"](https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs588/static/stack_smashing.pdf) and seem to be encountering a problem similar to what others have run into the past; however I cannot figure out why my code is still not working.

**What I'm trying to do:**

Consider the code below:

```
void function1(int a, int b, int c){
    char buffer1[8];
    // char buffer2[10];
    int *ret;

    ret = (int *) buffer1 + 24;
    (*ret) += 7; 
}

void main() {
    int x;

    x = 0;
    function1(1,2,3);
    x = 1;
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

The goal of the example is to overwrite the return address of *function1
* and skip the line x = 1 in main. So, the program should output 0 instead of 1. However, my output is still 1. So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

**Using gdb to calculate the return address and the offsets**

From an objdump of the assembly:

```
00000000000006db <main>:
 6db:   55                      push   %rbp
 6dc:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 6df:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
 6e3:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
 6ea:   ba 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edx
 6ef:   be 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%esi
 6f4:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 6f9:   e8 b2 ff ff ff          callq  6b0 <function1>
 6fe:   c7 45 fc 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
 705:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
 708:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
 70a:   48 8d 3d 93 00 00 00    lea    0x93(%rip),%rdi        # 7a4 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 711:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 716:   e8 45 fe ff ff          callq  560 <printf@plt>
 71b:   90                      nop
 71c:   c9                      leaveq 
 71d:   c3                      retq   
 71e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

Since I'm trying to skip `x = 1;`, 0x705 - 0x6fe = 0x7, which I'm confident is correct.
For determining the offset between buffer1 and the return address on the call stack, I inspect gdb:

```
Breakpoint 1, function1 (a=1, b=2, c=3) at example3.c:12
12      ret = (int *) buffer1 + 24;
(gdb) p $rbp
$1 = (void *) 0x7fffffffea80
(gdb) p &buffer1
$2 = (char (*)[8]) 0x7fffffffea70
```

The distance between buffer1 and the return address should then be: 0x7fffffffea80 - 0x7fffffffea70 + 8 = 24

I've also verified that the word size is 8 (using `arch` I know it's x86_64).

My guess is the return address offset might be different due to something like a stack canary, but how would I find the actual return address then?

EDIT:

The disassembly for function1:

```
00000000000006b0 <function1>:
 6b0:   55                      push   %rbp
 6b1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 6b4:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
 6b7:   89 75 e8                mov    %esi,-0x18(%rbp)
 6ba:   89 55 e4                mov    %edx,-0x1c(%rbp)
 6bd:   48 8d 45 f0             lea    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
 6c1:   48 83 c0 44             add    $0x44,%rax
 6c5:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
 6c9:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
 6cd:   8b 00                   mov    (%rax),%eax
 6cf:   8d 50 07                lea    0x7(%rax),%edx
 6d2:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
 6d6:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%rax)
 6d8:   90                      nop
 6d9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 6da:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: Can you add the disassembly for `function1`?

Comment: I've added it above.

Comment: The `add $0x44, %rax` doesn't seem consistent with the `buffer1 + 24` in your code (even accounting for my answer below).  Are you sure you have compiled the latest version of your source?

Comment: You're sort of right on this as well, the objdump was from an older version when I was playing around with different offset values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is your main problem, but I'm looking at

```
   ret = (int *) buffer1 + 24;
```

Cast has higher precedence than binary `+`, so this is `((int *)buffer1) + 24`.  The effect is that `ret` is set to an address which is 96 bytes higher than that of `buffer1`, since `sizeof(int) == 4`.

You probably meant to write

```
   ret = (int *)(buffer1 + 24);
```

Also, the return address is 64 bits, and `int` is 32 bits.  So you probably wanted to declare `ret` as `unsigned long *` instead of `int *`, and change the cast accordingly, so that your `*ret += 7` is a 64-bit add.  It's unlikely to actually make a difference because of alignments, but still it will look more correct.

Comment: Thank you! This was it, it works now. However, could you explain more why 24 would get multiplied by sizeof(int)? Not sure I completely understand that part.

Comment: @cloudy_eclispse: Normal C pointer arithmetic, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/394777/634919