# Finding an element in a 2-D static array without using operator []

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

Given static 2 Given static 2-D array as follow:

```
int m[4][6];
```

How do i access to `m[2][4]` without using operator[]?

Comment: Calculate a pointer with an offset.

Comment: https://aticleworld.com/access-two-dimensional-array-using-pointers-in-c/ should do what you are looking for

Comment: `*(*(m + 2) + 4)`.

Comment: can u be specific pls

Comment: thanks guys can i delete this. i'm a new-timer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```cpp
*(*(m+2) + 4)
```

This is what operator `[]` really do, here array will **dacay** to pointer.

a brief explaination for this:

in `*(m+2)`, `m` is used as a prvalue of `int(*)[4]` pointing to the firsrt 
"row" of `m`, then dereferencing `m+2` get the reference to the 1D array of the third "row".

Then, this result decay to `int*` prvalue again pointing to the first element of the third "row", then dereferencing `this_value + 4`, we successfully retrieve the 5th element of the 3rd row, which is the exact result you get by using `m[2][4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a classical pointer exersice to me.

Try to use the address of m and some pointer arithmetic.

```
int main(){
    int m[4][6];
    m[2][4] = 42; // Using [] only for testing

    int x = *(*(m + 2) + 4);
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```