# What is the need for (char*) typecasting in the own sizeof API?

Tags: c, operator-keyword, sizeof, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define my_sizeof(type) (&type+1) - (&type) 

int main()
{   
 int y;
 printf("size_of int: %ld\n", sizeof(y));
 printf("address of y = %x \n",&y);
 printf("address of y +1 = %x \n", &y+1);

 printf("The sizeof = %d\n", my_sizeof(y));
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
  size_of int:  4
  address of y =  26f890
  address of y +1 =  26f894
  The sizeof =  1
```

I am expecting the *my_sizeof* output as "4" (i.e., 26f894  - 26f890)  but it is printing as "1".

Suppose if I typecast it as `char*` (i.e., `(char*) (&type+1) - (char*)(&type)`) the output is "4".

Can anyone tell me the need for `(char*)` typecasting.?

Comment: You seem know that `pointer+1` adds a `sizeof(T)` to the value of the pointer. Similarly, `pointer1-pointer2` divides the difference by `sizeof(T)`.

Comment: also warning with the format you use to print

Comment: and if you do not understans @HolyBlackCat remarks the difference of two pointers (of the same type of course) is a number of elements. Yes if you cast to pointer to char you will have a diff of addresses of bytes

Comment: `my_sizeof` macro is expanded to this - `(ptr + 1) - ptr` which is, of course, result in `1`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Answer (score 1):

In this expression

```
(&type+1) - (&type)
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic. The difference between two pointers that point to elements of the same array or one past the last element of the array is equal to the number of elements between two pointers.

And an object of the type int in your system occupies 4 bytes then casting the pointers to the type char * yields 4.

From the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of
>   the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two
>   array elements....

For the pointer arithmetic a single object is considered as an array having one element.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected plenty UBs in the `printf`s

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define my_sizeof(type) ((char *)(&type+1) - (char *)(&type))

int main()
{   
 int y;
 printf("size_of int: %zu\n", sizeof(y));
 printf("address of y = %p \n",(void *)&y);
 printf("address of y +1 = %p \n", (void *)(&y+1));

 printf("The sizeof = %zu\n", my_sizeof(y));
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```