# Adding integer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, variables, integer

So, I was messing around with pointers in C

```
int o = 10;
int x = 20;
int *pA = NULL;
pA = &o;
```

and after adding an integer to the
pointer 
`pA += x;`
the address stored in the pointer changed from 
000000000061FE18 
to 
000000000061FE68

After checking the value the address was pointing to using `*pA` the value was 0 and I could add an integer to this address using

```
*pA += x;
```

and `*pA` became equal to 20, but the value stored in variable `o` was still 10.

Could anyone explain what happened here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Comment: Adding to a pointer advances the pointer by that many times the size of that to which it points. After all, `p[5]` is identical to `*(p + 5)`. So if `p[5]` gets the 6th `int` (for example), then `p + 5` must necessarily advance the pointer by the size of five `int` objects.

Comment: You never touch value of `o` It should still be `10` afterwards. Where do vou get `30``from?

Comment: my bad I forgot to mention that I added x to o too before adding to x to pointer on my code

Comment: Copy/paste only code that you tested, else you waste time/effort:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pA += x;` - The pointer `pA` itself is incremented by the value of `x` multiplied by the size of type `pA` is pointing to and is equal to the size of `x`, which is `int`.

So, assume `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(x)` is 4 and `x` has the value of `20`, you end up multiplying the pointer value of `pA` by `80` because `4` * `20` = `80`, which is matching to your test results.

`0x61FE68` - `0x61FE18` = `0x50` = `80d`.

> After adding an integer to the pointer
> `pA += x;` .... (and) checking the value the address was pointing to using `*pA` the value was 0...

Since you incremented the pointer `pA` itself by `20` * `sizeof(int)` with `pA += x;`, `pA` points no longer to any valid object and beyond the bounds of the object it should point to.

To increment the pointer in this way invokes *[undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)* as well as dereferencing this pointer.

That it displayed `0` is just happen arbitrary to the situation. You can't rely on anything. The value can change already at the next execution.

> ... and I could add an integer to this address using `*pA += x;` and `*pA` became equal to `20`.

The behavior is undefined as said above. `pA` does not point to any legally referenced object.

> ...but the value stored in variable `o` was still `30`.

`o` isn't changed at all. With the first statement `pA += x;` you incremented the pointer itself, not the object `o` `pA` pointed to at the first place.

> Could anyone explain what happened here?

You incremented the pointer `pA` by `sizeof(int)` * `20` with the first `pA += x;`. Everything else can't be really explained, because the behavior is just undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The new address pointed by a pointer, after a constant value is added to it, depends on the type it points to:

```
NewAddress = OldAddress + ConstantValue * sizeof ( Type )
```

So, **in plain math**, with `pA += x`, you have

```
new_address_pointed_by_pA = old_address_pointed_by_pA + x * sizeof( int )
```

And since `x=20` and an integer in your machine is 4 bytes big, this becomes

```
new_address_pointed_by_pA = old_address_pointed_by_pA + 20*4 = 
                          = old_address_pointed_by_pA + 80
```

That's exactly what you experience, as `0x61FE68 - 0x61FE58` = 0x50. Your addresses, in fact, are represented in hexadecimal format. So the new address is `0x50=80` beyond the old one, and that fits with the simple calculation I showed above.

---

What does that new address contain? Well, we don't know. It depends on the *history* of that specific memory location.

If it was never used, it's not surprising it contained `0`. And it was also expected that after `*pA = x` it contained 20. And, again, it is not surprising at all that the location it was originally pointing remains unchanged.

**But...** with that assignment you could have raised a segmentation fault exception. An OS usually raises this signal when a memory location not assigned to your task is accessed. 
So, pay attention when you *play* with pointers, making sure that any arithmetics performed on them leads to legal new values.

Comment: @P__J__ you misunderstood my goal. It was not C but plain arithmetics. My goal was showing to the OP the different steps to come to the result they experience. I usually listen to advices, but I don't want to switch to that expression. I could change my expression so that it is clear that it is a "plain didactic calculation"?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I did but you cant use this syntax for it. It is simple misleading. Put more effort in the explanation and the equations

Comment: @P__J__ I admit it was misleading. Could you review if now it is more clear, please?

Comment: @Gerhardh see my comment above. It was an admittedly  misleading attempt to show the steps in plain math, not C code. Now that I've changed the symbols it should be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a small program which should explain pointer arithmetic a bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINTDIFF(type, p1, p2) printf("sizeof(%s) = %zu p1=%p p2 = %p diff(bytes) = %zi \ndiff(objects) = %zi diff(bytes)/sizeof(%s) = %zi\n\n", \
                                #type, sizeof(type), \
                                (void *)(p1), \
                                (void*)(p2), \
                                ((char *)(p2) - (char *)(p1)), \
                                (p2) - (p1),\
                                #type, \
                                ((char *)(p2) - (char *)(p1)) / sizeof(type))


int main(void)
{
    short s;
    char c;
    int i;
    long long ll;
    long double ld;

    short *sp = &s;
    char *cp = &c;
    int *ip = &i;
    long long *llp = &ll;
    long double *ldp = &ld;

    PRINTDIFF(short, sp, sp + 10);
    PRINTDIFF(char, cp, cp + 500);
    PRINTDIFF(int, ip, ip + 5);
    PRINTDIFF(long long, llp, llp + 5);
    PRINTDIFF(long double, ldp, ldp + 5);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4eP3rc

And the result:

```
sizeof(short) = 2 p1=0x7ffe0660eb76 p2 = 0x7ffe0660eb8a diff(bytes) = 20 
diff(objects) = 10 diff(bytes)/sizeof(short) = 10

sizeof(char) = 1 p1=0x7ffe0660eb75 p2 = 0x7ffe0660ed69 diff(bytes) = 500 
diff(objects) = 500 diff(bytes)/sizeof(char) = 500

sizeof(int) = 4 p1=0x7ffe0660eb70 p2 = 0x7ffe0660eb84 diff(bytes) = 20 
diff(objects) = 5 diff(bytes)/sizeof(int) = 5

sizeof(long long) = 8 p1=0x7ffe0660eb68 p2 = 0x7ffe0660eb90 diff(bytes) = 40 
diff(objects) = 5 diff(bytes)/sizeof(long long) = 5

sizeof(long double) = 16 p1=0x7ffe0660eb50 p2 = 0x7ffe0660eba0 diff(bytes) = 80 
diff(objects) = 5 diff(bytes)/sizeof(long double) = 5
```

BTW when you learn you should experiment yourself writing the short programs which will help you understand the C language. There is no easy, effortless way of learning C