# Pointer arithmetic confussion

Tags: c

Im having a hard time trying to figure out what of the to following options is the second line of code doing and why.

1. Substracting 1xsizeof(t_stackFrame) to the memory direction of baseStack
2. Subtracting 1 to the memory direction of baseStack
3. Subtracting 1xsizeof(t_stackFrame*) (equals to 8 bytes in x64) to the memory direction of baseStack

Here's the code:

```c
static void* initializeStackFrame(void* entryPoint, void* baseStack) {
      t_stackFrame* frame = (t_stackFrame*)baseStack - 1;
      frame->gs = 0x001;
      frame->fs = 0x002;
      frame->r15 = 0x003;
      frame->r14 = 0x004;
      frame->r13 = 0x005;
      frame->r12 = 0x006;
      frame->r11 = 0x007;
      frame->r10 = 0x008;
      frame->r9 = 0x009;
      frame->r8 = 0x00A;
      frame->rsi = 0x00B;
      frame->rdi = 0x00C;
      frame->rbp = 0x00D;
      frame->rdx = 0x00E;
      frame->rcx = 0x00F;
      frame->rbx = 0x010;
      frame->rax = 0x011;
      frame->rip = (uint64_t)entryPoint;
      frame->cs = 0x008;
      frame->eflags = 0x202;
      frame->rsp = (uint64_t) & (frame->base);
      frame->ss = 0x000;
      frame->base = 0x000;

      return (void*)(frame);
}
```

Comment: take a look at this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/394774/4249714](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394774/4249714)

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic is defined in terms of the pointed-to type.  This code ...

> ```
>     t_stackFrame* frame = (t_stackFrame*)baseStack - 1;
> ```

...

1. converts the value of `baseStack` from type `void *` to type `t_stackFrame *` (because casts have higher precedence than subtractions or assignments), then
2. treating the result as a pointer into an array of `t_stackFrame`s, computes a pointer to the (start of) the element immediately preceding the one to which the original pointer points, and finally
3. assigns the result to variable `frame`.

That's more or less you alternative (1).

Comment: awesome, so it's like assigning &(baseStack[-1])? (assuming baseStack is casted to t_stackFrame)

Comment: @FRANCISCOBERNAD, yes, it is exactly equivalent to `&(((t_stackFrame*)baseStack)[-1])`, as you say.