# Subtracting 1 from a string

Tags: c, string, char

```
char r[255], word[255], * ind;
    int n = 0;
    gets_s(r);
    gets_s(word);
    ind = r - 1;
    while (ind = strstr(ind+1 , word))n++;

    printf("%d\n", n);
```

This is a code that my friend sent me for an assignment. We have to find how many times a given word (`word` in code) appears in a sentence (`r` in code). Now I don't understand this part `ind=r-1`. What happens when we subtract a number from a string?? After playing around and testing the code it seems that this needs to be implemented so that if a word that we check for is the first word in the sentence it will also check it and include it into the final tally `n`.
So the question is **what happens when we subtract a number like `1` from a string**. Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: It's [pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic) -- you're not subtracting from the string, but from the pointer to the first element of the string. The subtraction is used so that the first `strstr` call will start searching from the correct location.

Comment: Note that you can use arrays everywhere where a pointer is valid – in such cases, the array *decays* to a pointer to its first element automatically.