# characters & pointers and Arithmetic?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dereference

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    float arr[5] = {12.5, 10.0, 13.5, 90.5, 0.5};
    float *ptr1 = &arr[0];
    float *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
    cout<<*ptr2<<" ";
    cout<<ptr2 - ptr1;

    return 0;
}
```

Correct output of this code is -> 90.5 3

But I am unable to get the concept behind it. please if anybody can explain how we got this output.

Comment: Works [here](https://onlinegdb.com/-gKpPlGP6)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic)

Comment: `ptr1` points at `arr[0]` since you initialised it that way.   `ptr2` points at `arr[3]` since you initialised it with the value `ptr1 + 3` which is equivalent to `&arr[0 + 3]`.    This is because pointer arithmetic takes account of what the pointer points at.    So the difference between `ptr2` and `ptr` is measured in number of `float`s, not number of characters.

Comment: One thing you could try is to change `float *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;` to `float *ptr2 = ptr1 + 2;` or  `float *ptr2 = ptr1 + 4;` and see what difference it makes.