# How does the pointer arithmetic operator ++ work in C?

Tags: c

Is ++ in C pointer a kind of operator overloading, which is similar to C++?

How does this pointer arithmetic work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int i[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  int    *pi = i;
  double f[5] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
  double *pf = f;

  printf("sizeof int:%lu bytes\tsizeof double:%lu bytes\t\n",
          sizeof (int), sizeof (double));
  printf("i[0]: %d \tMemAddress:%p\t\n", *pi, pi);
  printf("i[1]: %d \tMemAddress:%p\t\n", *++pi, pi);
  printf("f[0]: %f \tMemAddress:%p\t\n", *pf, pf);
  printf("f[1]: %f \tMemAddress:%p\t\n", *++pf, pf);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try reading Chapter 5 of K&R.  It should give you most of the answers you are looking for.

Comment: Pointers are just numbers, the `++` operator works the same as it does for any other numeric type (other than it increments by the size of the pointed to type rather than by 1)

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with operator overloading and also works the same in C and C++.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394767/pointer-arithmetic

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73931991/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`++`-ing / `--`-ing a pointer in C adds or subtracts `sizeof(the type that pointer points to)` to the pointer.

e.g.

Assume that an int takes up 4 bytes in memory, and there's an int pointer named `p` that points to some memory address, like `0x10000000`. `p++` will cause `p` to point to `0x10000004`.

Comment: That looks like a copyright violation.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73932057/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Comment: An illustration may make sense for pointers, but it should be your own work. [Plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun) is unacceptable.

Comment: Even if it is [Creative Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license), there are ***attribution requirements***.