# Addition of an integer to a string

Tags: c, pointers, char, addition

I have this code in c and it's working properly.

```
char* str2 = string + (str_len - end_len);
```

`str_len` and `end_len` are two integers and `string` is another char pointer string.

I don't understand why I am able to add an integer to a character pointer string.

Shouldn't this give a type error?

Comment: Read about pointer arithmetic. You say it works, but works for what?

Comment: Remember: if `a` is a pointer and `i` is an `int` (or another integer type), then `a[i] == *(a + i)` — so the addition of integers and pointers is legitimate.

Comment: ok i'll read about pointers. It's just that I had never seen an integer being added to a string like this.

Comment: there's no string in C. `char*` is just an array. There's no string operations except several functions that work on null-terminated strings stored in a char array

Comment: clang, I think, has a -Wstring-plus-int option to generate warnings.  Not sure where it's documented though.  To me it's perfectly good code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja guess

Comment: We should not have to gues, @AntasSharma.  Ideally, your question should contain an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  Our assumptions about what you mean could be horribly wrong — we don't know the types of any of the three variables `string`, `str_len`, `end_len`.  We can make intelligent guesses, but we should not have to guess.

Comment: @phuclv: there are strings in C — see the C Standard (C11): [§7.1.1 Definitions of terms ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1) where it says _"A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character. "_. C does not have a full-blown string type, but it most definitely has strings.

Comment: See also [With arrays, why is it the case that `a[5] == 5[a]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/15168) and [Pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394767/15168).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't declare many variables in this snippet but I have mentioned their data types. 
Also, I feel like people are overthinking this. This was probably not a question that I should have asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str2` will be assigned the pointer value of  `string` + `(str_len - end_len)`.  If `offset = str_len - end_len` < 0 or `offset` > size of `string` (array) + 1 then it's undefined behavior (note: `sizeof "hello "` counts the trailing '\0' for a string hence the `-1`).  Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string[] = "hello world";
    char *str2 = string + (sizeof "hello " - 1);
    printf("%s\n", str2);
}
```

prints:

```
world
```