# How to interpret *(ptr) and *(ptr+2) in arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

I don't understand how pointers works exactly in arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

  int x[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  int* ptr;

  // ptr is assigned the address of the third element
  ptr = &x[2]; 

  printf("value ptr = %d \n", *ptr);   // 3
  printf("address ptr = %d \n", ptr);   // 3
  printf("value ptr+2 = %d \n", *(ptr+2)); // 4
  printf("address ptr+2 = %d \n", (ptr+2)); // 4

  return 0;
}
```

The result:

> ```
> value ptr = 3
> address ptr = -1931225192
> value ptr+2 = 5
> address ptr+2 = -1931225184
> ```

The difference between `ptr` and `ptr + 2` are 8 bytes.
So when `ptr` is equal to `-1931225192` then why isn't `ptr + 2` equal to `-1931225192 + 2` but instead it is `-1931225192 - 8`?

Can someone explain how this works? Because it is logical to add 2 to the original value which was `-1931225192` but instead this +2 changes into -8.

Comment: `why ptr + 2 isn't equal to -1931225192 + 2 but instead it is -1931225192 - 8` Its not `+2` but __`+8`__ (not -8) exactly because `The difference between ptr and ptr + 2 are 8 bytes.`.

Comment: You should be using `%p` to print pointers, not `%d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you add an integer to a pointer, you are not adding a fixed number of bytes. You are adding a fixed number of **elements**. This means you are implicitly adding `n*sizeof(int)` bytes. To avoid this, you can cast your array to a `char *` if you want to strictly add a number of bytes.

   Think about it this way: Since the `ptr[n]` accesses a given **element** and is defined to be equivalent to `*(ptr + n)`, we see that `(ptr + n)` without the `*` simply gets the address of `ptr[n]`.
2. The address converted to an integer is appears to be negative number, so adding a positive value decreases its magnitude. So the `+2` changes to a `+8` not a `-8`.

Comment: For the number 2. I was pretty wrong there it wasn't -8 but +8. 

For the number 1. So it is the same as ptr + n*sizeof(int) in this case ptr+2*sizeof(int) ? That is weird I thought that it goes with intuition like ptr + 2 and not ptr 2*sizeof(int). 

Good to know.

Comment: @Jackob2001 Yep. Pointer arithmetic carries an implicit `*sizeof(*ptr)`.

Comment: I have one more question. Then if let's say -1931225192 contains value 3 then what -1931225191 contains ? Can I add in -1931225191 a different value ?

Comment: @Jackob2001 Undefined behavior. If you try to access an address that is not a multiple of the alignment requirement of the type, the behavior is undefined and the result is non-deterministic. Typically `int` is 4 bytes and also has 4 bytes alignment so if you try to access an `int` pointer that is not a multiple of 4, this can be problematic.

Comment: I've got one more and it is a last question because I came up with it now. What happens if I write *(ptr + 2*sizeof(int)) ? Will it then be *(ptr + (2*sizeof(int))*sizeof(int)) ? What I am trying to say is instead of *(ptr + 2) I want to change  using instead of +2 the 2*sizeof(int) (because as you said this 2 is changes into 2*sizeof(int)) will it be the same or something will change ?

Comment: @Jackob2001 If you write `*(ptr + 2*sizeof(int))` then yes that will advance by 2 times however many bytes happen to be in an int **elements**. Or advance by 2 times `sizeof(int)` times `sizeof(int)` again bytes.

Comment: hmmm so in fact *(ptr + 2*sizeof(int)) will result in ptr + 8*sizeof(int) I guess. I thought that I could change the *(ptr + 2) into *(ptr + 2*sizeof(int)) because when you said that this 2 is changed into 2*sizeof(int) then maybe they are similar. I tried to create a similar effect using sizeof(int). The program when he sees *(ptr + 2), how he changes the formula ? Somewhere outside of the main program or changes the formula to something similar to *(ptr + 2) or is it something built in ? I don't know if my question is also clear ;> Those pointers are sometimes weird.

Comment: @Jackob2001 It's the built-in behavior of pointer arithmetic. The only way the 'formula' can change is if the size of the integer changes, or if you cast the pointer to be of a different type. If you want to add a fixed number of **bytes** then try casting the pointer to `char *` like this `*(int *)((char *)ptr + 2*sizeof(int))` which is the same thing as `*(ptr + 2)`.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand this * (int *)((char *)ptr + 2*sizeof(int)). But I am very glad you've told me ;> I am pretty new to pointers but reading how they act is weird somethimes this one you've shown isn't any different ;> like int * or * (int *) or the rest. I need more practice ... Still thank you very much !

Comment: @Jackob2001 I'm glad to have been of help. Basically what `*(int *)((char *)ptr + 2*sizeof(int))` does is convert the pointer-to-`int` to a pointer-to-`char` and since `sizeof(char)` is always equal to 1 the implicit `*sizeof(char)` does nothing. So this way you add a fixed number of bytes the the pointer. And then you convert the pointer back to an `int *` and then dereference it.

Comment: sometimes seeing so many " * " confuses me of which one is pointer and which one is just multiplication ... But I assume that int *  is a int pointer and * (int *) value at pointer int. Hmmm although doesn't (char *) changes the type of ptr which was int at the beggining which changes the address value ? isn't the implicit n*sizeof(char) in which n = 2*sizeof(int) I guess ? It's so confusing. Because char is not the same as int so a number like 5 in int will be changes in char ?

Comment: @Jackob2001 Only the addition (`+`) changes the address value. The cast/type conversion (`(char *)`) does not change the value of the pointer immediately but it changes how the `+` operator behaves on it, and thus the value of the resulting calculation.

Comment: I don't understand. When I write int* ptr; then I know that when I write ptr = &x[2] then I know that the value is int and the address like you said will have 4 bytes between x[1] and x[2] or x[2] and x[3]. Char has one byte so the ptr = &x[2] will change the address and the difference will be 1 byte ? between ptr[1] and ptr[2] when x[1] and x[2] are 4 bytes difference. That's confusing. Idk if to change it into chat because as I said pointers are hard to read or understand at the beggining.

Comment: Let's say char * ptr = &x[2], but x[2] is an int value so how it works ? and (int *)(char* ptr) how it then works or is it (int *)(char* ptr) = &x[2]. I am a bit confused. I only understand (I guess) the int* ptr = &x[2] which indicated the address of an int value address.

Comment: @Jackob2001 If you write `char *ptr = &x[2];` but if `x` was `int *x;` then the difference will still be 8 bytes, because the pointer arithmetic was performed before, and then it was assigned/converted to a `char *`.

Comment: I don't get it that much, could you tell me more specific like step by step how to analize it ? Because I know ptr was before int and some arithmetics were made before. But I can't follow that much, also I understand that only data type was changed in ptr from int to char but the addresses weren't changed which I still don't get it. Sorry for any problem ;<

Comment: @Jackob2001 `int *x = something; char *ptr = &x[2];` So first, the `&x[2]` offsets `x` by 2 elements, and since `x` is an `int *` each element is an `int` so each element is `sizeof(int)` or 4 bytes. So `&x[2]` gets the address stored in `x` but offset by `2*sizeof(int)` or 8 bytes. This new value is **then** implicitly converted to `char *` and stored in `ptr`.

Comment: won't there appear then again sizeof(char) made from (char * ) and again sizeof(int) made from * (int * ) ? because when does this arithmetic applyes ? *ptr = * (int * ptr) so   * (ptr + 2) = *(int * (ptr+2)) ?  I got confused when sizeof(int) and sizeof(char) appear in * (int * )((char * )ptr + 2*sizeof(int)). which one of them is "n*sizeof(...)" or else what *( int*) sees in

Comment: @Jackob2001 I am not quite sure what you're asking there. Also you could surround the code with backtick \` characters to make it more readable.

Comment: Ahh yes sorry. I'm still struggeling with the syntax. Okey let's say we have `*(ptr)` which is the same as `*( int* ptr)` then `*(ptr+2)` is also equivelant to `*(int* ptr+2)` ?. Also `*(int *)((char *)ptr + 2*sizeof(int))` there is one sizeof(int) which was in the code. Then there is char which sees `*ptr +  2*sizeof(int)` so it is the same as `*ptr + (2*sizeof(int))*sizeof(char))` ?? and after char there is int so now the n is `(2*sizeof(int))*sizeof(char))` so now I have `*(char* ptr +(2*sizeof(int))*sizeof(char)*sizeof(int))` ???? I got lost here

Comment: basically I am more confused with sizeof when it appears when I use this way like you writted `*(int *)((char *)ptr + 2*sizeof(int))`. All I know is that `*ptr` is the same as `* (int * ptr)` but what is with `*(ptr+2)` is like when I add int* in it, the 2 there is used in sizeof. But in your example `*(int *)((char *)ptr + 2*sizeof(int))` what is putted in sizeof char and sizeof int ? It's hard to understand what is written in here when there are to many pointers. Is this question better ?

Comment: @Jackob2001 I was saying that `*(int *)((char *)ptr + 2*sizeof(int))` and `*(ptr+2)` do the same thing, assuming `int *ptr;`. `sizeof(char)` is always equal to 1 and `sizeof(int)` is typically equal to four. The reason is because `*(ptr+2)` adds `2*sizeof(int)` bytes because it adds 2 elements. But if you cast to a `char *` first, then adding 2 would add only 2 bytes. Because with `char` an element and a byte are the same thing. But if we manually multiply 2 with the number of bytes in an int, we manually emulate the automatic implied multiplication by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: okey wait so if I understand `(char *)ptr + 2*sizeof(int)` is the same as          `(ptr +2*sizeof(int)*sizeof(char))` ? and then there is `(int *)(ptr + 2sizeof(int)*sizeof(char))` which then is the same as `ptr + 2sizeof(int)*sizeof(char)*sizeof(int)`. And at last there is * at the end so it changes into value ??? there are so many pointers that I lost track of to the size of is the result of 2*4*1*4 I guess. I trust you that your code is equal to `*(ptr+2)` all I am trying to do is change `*ptr` into `*(int *ptr)` and maybe this is also correct `*(ptr+2)` into `*(int* ptr + 2)`

Comment: and the same with your long code because I don't understand how every int and char works here what *(int *) sees in `((char *)ptr +2*sizeof(int)`. does he sees it as *(int *ptr + 2*sizeof(int)*sizeof(char))? or what the pointers make me dizzy because I don't know what is the arythemtic and I need step by step what it sees ... sorry for bother

Comment: I just don't get it how to read these pointers because I understand I guess only the *(ptr +2) but *(int *)ptr + 2 or something similar not really I don't know when the arithmetics apply and when not, where the size of is and when not.

Comment: @Jackob2001 `*(int *ptr)` is actually not valid syntax. Did you mean `*(int *)ptr`?

Comment: @Jackob2001 `(ptr + 2*sizeof(int)*sizeof(char))` is not equal to `(ptr + 2)`. The only thing that the type conversions (changing it to a `char *` or `int *`) changes is the behavior of the dereference operator `*` and the addition operator `+`. If you add 2 to a pointer, the number of bytes added depends on the type of the pointer. If you dereference a pointer, the result depends on the type of the pointer. Basically when I write `(char *)ptr` all that means is 'Interpret `ptr` as a pointer-to-`char` instead of a pointer-to-`int`.'

Comment: I guess ? I am not that great in pointers yes. I just know that ptr is the same as int* ptr. What do you think of the rest of what I said.

Comment: '`(int *)(ptr + 2sizeof(int)*sizeof(char))` which then is the same as`ptr + 2sizeof(int)*sizeof(char)*sizeof(int)`' eh not really. Casting does not add a times `sizeof` type each time you cast. By the way, since `ptr` is already of type `int` then `(int *)ptr` is the same as just `ptr` because converting a type to itself does nothing.

Comment: Hmm maybe I understand it so there will be only one additional sizeof which is char ? Because ((char*)ptr +sizeof(int)) where sizeof(int) is the number after the arithmetics there will be only one address after adding *ptr address and +8 out of sizeof(char)*sizeof(int) operation for example the final result is 50100 and 50108 is the result so now it is passed from char to int so (int *)(50108) which does I guess nothing because n = 0 now so 0*sizeof(int) and interpreted as number ???

Comment: @Jackob2001 When you write `((char *)ptr + sizeof(int))` you are adding `sizeof(int)` elements to the pointer. Just like `&ptr[sizeof(int)]`. But for a `char` an 'element' is a byte so you are just adding `sizeof(int)` bytes to the pointer. I hope this clears things up, sorry if I'm bad at explaining.

Comment: I mean is my explanation wrong I just assume that sizeof(char) is 1 but still added there to see if I am right or not. Because the final result that the *(int *) sees is just an address in which element is 0 like address is 50108 so *(int *)(50108) - this number after arithmetics, there will be no arithmetics for int because there is no "+" hence n = 0 so 0*sizeof(int) = 0 so we are left with *(50108) I guess. I don't mean you are bad at explaining it is just pointers are hard to read ... I believe you understand me. btw why do we convert char into int if arithmetics won't change anything here

Comment: @Jackob2001 I'm not saying you *should* convert to char, I am saying that is something you *can* do *if* you ever want to offset a pointer by a fixed number of *bytes* because yes, a `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1. Yes, if you convert a pointer to another pointer type but then do not perform any arithmetics the value will be unchanged. But keep in mind that the dereference operator `*` means to read a value at a pointer. So even if a pointer is the same, `*(int *)ptr` will read 4 bytes from the address, whereas `*(char *)ptr` will only read a single one.

Comment: A ok good to know, so I was right that the sizeof(int) at the end won't exist because the n = 0 ? like with the example ? "*(int *)(50108) - this number after arithmetics, there will be no arithmetics for int because there is no "+" hence n = 0 so 0*sizeof(int) = 0 so we are left with *(50108) I guess." ?

Comment: @Jackob2001 Yes, that's right.

Comment: Wow, ok thanks, that was pretty hard but I think I got it. I need to find more sources teaching the pointers because it sometimes goes messy. So the only arithmetics appears only in Char which then the Int isn't applying the arithmetics because the "+" isn't there anymore.

Comment: @Jackob2001 I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394767/16217248).

Comment: Usually the syntax was the problem but I think I got the idea. Using my words for your example the arythmetics worked only on Char because it had "+" between the pointer and the number, after that it is changed into one address and passed from char to int. But Int doesn't apply another arythmetics because there is no "+" anymore so there is only a pointer to the new address made by arythmetics with char and sizeof(int). That's all I guess.

Comment: @user1627248 Why `*(int *ptr)` is a syntax error ? Because when we define the pointer we write int `*ptr` and I don't do `(int *) ptr`. Because when I write int `*ptr` then it is equal to `ptr` so adding this to ptr : *(ptr) then instead of ptr I put int *ptr that I've defined. Why not it is syntax error and have to change into (int *) ptr ? I cannot find any example why I have to use it like that because it only says about `int *ptr` not `(int*)ptr`. Even here nothing is about it https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-pointers/.

Comment: @Jackob2001 Because we use `int *ptr;` to declare a **new** variable of type `int *`. But to convert an existing variable to type `int *` we have to use `(int *)`. By the way `(int *ptr)` might be parsed as `int` times `ptr` but `int` is a type and not a variable so that ain't happening.

Answer (score 0):

For starters these two calls of `printf`

```
printf("adress ptr = %d \n", ptr);   // 3
printf("adress ptr+2 = %d \n", (ptr+2)); // 4
```

have undefined behavior because there are used the incorrect conversion specifier `d` designed for integers to output pointers. You need to write

```
printf("adress ptr = %p \n", ( void * )ptr);   // 3
printf("adress ptr+2 = %p \n", ( void * )(ptr+2)); // 4
```

After this assignment

```
ptr = &x[2];
```

the pointer `ptr` points to the element `x[2]` of the array `x`. So dereferencing the pointer like `*ptr` you will get the element `x[2]` the value of which is equal to `3`.

You may rewrite the above assignment the following way

```
ptr = x + 2;
```

The expression `ptr + 2` points to the second element of the array `x` after the element `x[2]` that is to the element `x[4]`. Dereferencing the expression `*( ptr + 2 )` you will get the element `x[4]` the value of which is equal to `5`.

The difference between the values of pointer expressions `ptr` and `ptr + 2` is equal to `2 * sizeof( int )`.

As you are using the incorrect conversion specifier to output pointers then you have negative numbers

```
adress ptr = -1931225192

and

adress ptr+2 = -1931225184
```

Nevrtheless the difference between these numbers is equal to `2 * sizeof( int )`. As mentioned above you need to use the cirrect conversion specifier `p` to output valid values of the pointer expressions.

In general if you have an array for example `x` and a pointer `ptr` that is initialized by the address of the first element of the array `x` like for example

```
int x[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int* ptr = x;
```

then the expression `ptr + i` points to the `i-th` element of the array `x`. This is the so-called pointer arithmetic. A difference berween two points that point to elements of some array is equal to the number of elements between the elements pointed to by the pointers.

In this declaration

```
int* ptr = x;
```

the array designator `x` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. This declaration actually is equivalent to

```
int* ptr = &x[0];
```